# Remove empty array elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

Some elements in my array are empty strings from users. `$linksArray` still has empty elements after the following:

```
foreach($linksArray as $link)
{
    if($link == '')
    {
        unset($link);
    }
}
print_r($linksArray);
```

The `empty()` function doesn't work either.

Comment: I thought it was worth mentioning that the code above does not work because unset(...) operates on the variable created by the foreach loop, not the original array that obviously stays as it was before the loop.

Comment: if(!empty($link))
    {
       echo $link;
    } this works for me

Comment: U are changing a $link that is not refferenced!
use foreach($linksArray as $key => $link) unset(linksArray[$key])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Answer (score 2016, accepted):

As you're dealing with an array of strings, you can simply use [`array_filter()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), which conveniently handles all this for you:

```
$linksArray = array_filter($linksArray);
```

Keep in mind that **if no callback is supplied**, all entries of array equal to `FALSE` (see [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed. So if you need to preserve elements that are i.e. exact string `'0'`, you will need a custom callback:

```
// PHP 7.4 and later
print_r(array_filter($linksArray, fn($value) => !is_null($value) && $value !== ''));

// PHP 5.3 and later
print_r(array_filter($linksArray, function($value) { return !is_null($value) && $value !== ''; }));

// PHP < 5.3
print_r(array_filter($linksArray, create_function('$value', 'return $value !== "";')));
```

Note: If you need to reindex the array after removing the empty elements, use:

```
$linksArray = array_values(array_filter($linksArray));
```

Comment: That was a typo haha, sorry. It's correct in my real code. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I would use `empty` over `== ''`. But thanks for the reference :)

Comment: `array_filter` should remove the empty elements. And if PHP's definition of empty isn't quite the same as your definition, then you can fill in the callback option with an anonymous function that throws out unwanted elements. Apparently you must have php 5.3 or later to use anonymous call backs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412299/how-do-you-use-anonymous-functions-in-php

Comment: it always pays to fully read the documentation. I didn't know it auto-filtered out empty elements. Thanks @BoltClock.

Comment: use array_filter($linksArray,'trim');

Comment: watch out array_filter doesnt reindex array indexes (a problem may occur in using processes array in for statement). 

So wrap it all with array_values function.

Comment: Use this function for a multidimensional array: `$linksArray = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $linksArray));`

Comment: not better   foreach (array_keys($locations,"") as $k)  unset($locations[$k]);

Comment: Take `$a = array('a'=>5, 'b'=>6, 'a'=>5);`, then `array_filter($a));`, the result is `array('a'=>5, 'b'=>6)` - `array_filter()` removes duplicates too, so not so good for just removing nulls.

Comment: Answer is incorrect, because it will remove `false` elements too. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @Deji have you tried printing that array before filtering it?  I think setting `a` the second time just resets the first one.

Comment: @Cranio: which is already covered by another comment. It is not incorrect, but perhaps *broader* than **your** requirements. That doesn't mean other people can't find it helpful still; after all, if all you have is strings in your array, this answer will remove only the empty ones.

Comment: I wish someone had told me that 4 years ago.

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer with PHP 7.4 version (arrow functions) and adding a warning about deprecated `create_function()`?

Comment: @Dharman: Done. I don't think I need to say that create_function() is deprecated since there's already a note saying to use it for older versions of PHP, but I moved it to the bottom.

Comment: This was really helpfull because was getting empty strings on a dynamic form, thank you really much. used atm 5.3 later, as im not using atm php 7.4 only 7.1.

Comment: watch out: array_filter takes an array and returns an object. So how to get an array returned instead of an object?

Comment: @Imran_Developer: When did that happen? I just checked the manual and it doesn't mention this behavior having changed. array_filter() returns an array.

Comment: @BoltClock dear, I am working with APIs and got a different JSON response so I was surprised, it really changes the behavior. i have double-checked with postman

Answer (score 200):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove empty elements:

```
$emptyRemoved = array_filter($linksArray);
```

If you have `(int) 0` in your array, you may use the following:

```
$emptyRemoved = remove_empty($linksArray);

function remove_empty($array) {
  return array_filter($array, '_remove_empty_internal');
}

function _remove_empty_internal($value) {
  return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Maybe your elements are not empty per se but contain one or more spaces... You can use the following before using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
$trimmedArray = array_map('trim', $linksArray);
```

Comment: I just added it to the accepted answer by BoltClock, you could simply do array_filter($foo, 'strlen') to avoid the "0" issue and only remove those with zero length.

Comment: @nezZario: Assuming you only have `scalar` items in your array yes. Otherwise, you cannot do that.

Comment: Using lambda for php >= 5.3 `function remove_empty($array) {
  return array_filter($array, function($value){return !empty($value) || $value === 0;});
}`

Comment: `array_map()` did the magic cos I had spaces in those empty arrays!

Answer (score 189):

The most popular answer on this topic is absolutely INCORRECT.

Consider the following PHP script:

```
<?php
$arr = array('1', '', '2', '3', '0');
// Incorrect:
print_r(array_filter($arr));
// Correct:
print_r(array_filter($arr, 'strlen'));
```

Why is this?  Because a string containing a single '0' character also evaluates to boolean false, so even though it's not an empty string, it will still get filtered.  That would be a bug.

Passing the built-in strlen function as the filtering function will work, because it returns a non-zero integer for a non-empty string, and a zero integer for an empty string.  Non-zero integers always evaluate to true when converted to boolean, while zero integers always evaluate to false when converted to boolean.

So, the absolute, definitive, correct answer is:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, 'strlen');
```

Comment: Agreed. This should be the accepted answer, for those whose array contains strings

Comment: Upvoted. A better answer than many of the others, however it should be noted that the currently-accepted answer is technically not incorrect since "empty" does, indeed, have special meaning within PHP.  (Some values that qualify as "empty": `0`, `""`, `null`)

Comment: They are not incorrect, it's all about context. In some cases preserving the value 0 could be important. So please, don't say that everyone is wrong except you

Comment: This breaks if the array contains another array: `strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: You can say that this can also be a good approach (instead of saying others incorrect)to achieve one's desired actions.Basically not all the cases are similar .Although this approach is working for my case.

Comment: And if you want to filter out null values and other none scalar types you can use `'is_scalar'`. Do note that in this case, an empty string would be allowed.

Comment: Take care if you are dealing with nested arrays as @hpaknia said. This solution only works with arrays of strings.

Comment: From PHP8.1 `strlen` is no longer a good technique because it will generate Deprecations. `Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated`

Answer (score 110):

```
$linksArray = array_filter($linksArray);
```

"If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed." -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I also tried this after Google'ing the problem. Unfortunately, it leaves in the blank elements for me.

Comment: @Will: are you sure? It removes also empty strings, I successfully tested this. Maybe your input values contain spaces and should be trimmed before. According to the [boolean conversion rules](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) the empty string is evaluated to false and therefore removed by array_filter.

Answer (score 58):

```
    $myarray = array_filter($myarray, 'strlen');  //removes null values but leaves "0"
    $myarray = array_filter($myarray);            //removes all null values
```

Comment: strlen also removes false :(

Comment: Only if false is a string.  A boolean false has no strring length.

Comment: From PHP8.1 `strlen` is no longer a good technique because it will generate Deprecations. `Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated`

Answer (score 45):

You can just do

```
array_filter($array)
```

array_filter: "If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE will be removed." This means that elements with values NULL, 0, '0', '', FALSE, array() will be removed too.

The other option is doing

```
array_diff($array, array(''))
```

which will remove elements with values NULL, '' and FALSE.

Hope this helps :)

### UPDATE

Here is an example.

```
$a = array(0, '0', NULL, FALSE, '', array());

var_dump(array_filter($a));
// array()

var_dump(array_diff($a, array(0))) // 0 / '0'
// array(NULL, FALSE, '', array());

var_dump(array_diff($a, array(NULL))) // NULL / FALSE / ''
// array(0, '0', array())
```

To sum up:

- 0 or '0' will remove 0 and '0'
- NULL, FALSE or '' will remove NULL, FALSE and ''

Answer (score 43):

```
foreach($linksArray as $key => $link) 
{ 
    if($link === '') 
    { 
        unset($linksArray[$key]); 
    } 
} 
print_r($linksArray);
```

Comment: A concise, readable and safe solution that doesn't remove `false` and `0`. Considering this was posted **the same minute** as the accepted answer (that is unsafe and incorrect), I can only assume your 8 upvotes compared to the accepted answer's 649 is down to the latter being a one-line solution.

Comment: @rybo111 - possibly, though using that logic in a callback to `array_filter()` would be a cleaner approach than a `foreach()` loop

Comment: Perhaps quicker, but your solution is the most readable, which is important. For those using your solution requiring `trim()`, I would recommend `if(is_string($link) && trim($link) === '')`

Answer (score 38):

#### In short:

This is my suggested code:

```
$myarray =  array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $myarray), 'strlen'));
```

#### Explanation:

I thinks use `array_filter` is good, but not enough, because values be like `space` and `\n`,... keep in the array and this is usually bad.

So I suggest you use mixture ‍‍`array_filter` and `array_map`.

`array_map` is for trimming, `array_filter` is for remove empty values, `strlen` is for keep `0` value, and `array_values` is for re indexing if you needed.

#### Samples:

```
$myarray = array("\r", "\n", "\r\n", "", " ", "0", "a");

// "\r", "\n", "\r\n", " ", "a"
$new1 = array_filter($myarray);

// "a"
$new2 = array_filter(array_map('trim', $myarray));

// "0", "a"
$new3 = array_filter(array_map('trim', $myarray), 'strlen');

// "0", "a" (reindex)
$new4 = array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $myarray), 'strlen'));

var_dump($new1, $new2, $new3, $new4);
```

#### Results:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
" string(1) "
  [1]=>
  string(1) "
"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "
"
  [4]=>
  string(1) " "
  [6]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
array(1) {
  [6]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
array(2) {
  [5]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

#### Online Test:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e02f5d8795938be9f0fa6f4c17245a9bf8777404

Answer (score 36):

Another one liner to remove empty ("" empty string) elements from your array.

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($a) {return $a !== "";});
```

*Note: This code deliberately keeps `null`, `0` and `false` elements.*

---

Or maybe you want to trim your array elements first:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($a) {
    return trim($a) !== "";
});
```

*Note: This code also removes `null` and `false` elements.*

Comment: Exactly what I neeeded, and this is also compatible with [older PHPs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485336/closures-or-create-function-in-php), thanks! ;-)

Comment: @JohnK Wrong. To do this exactly like the user whants to the callback **is** needed, unless you want to remove alzo zeroes and other falsey values.

Answer (score 14):

If you are working with a numerical array and need to re-index the array after removing empty elements, use the **[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)** function:

```
array_values(array_filter($array));
```

Also see: [PHP reindex array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558022/php-reindex-array)

Answer (score 14):

**The most voted answer is *wrong* or at least not completely true as the OP is talking about blank strings only. Here's a thorough explanation:**

## What does *empty* mean?

First of all, we must agree on what *empty* means. Do you mean to filter out:

1. the **empty strings** only ("")?
2. the **strictly false** values? (`$element === false`)
3. the **falsey** values? (i.e. 0, 0.0, "", "0", NULL, array()...)
4. the equivalent of PHP's `empty()` function?

## How do you filter out the values

To filter out **empty strings only**:

```
$filtered = array_diff($originalArray, array(""));
```

To only filter out **strictly *false*** values, you must use a *callback* function:

```
$filtered = array_diff($originalArray, 'myCallback');
function myCallback($var) {
    return $var === false;
}
```

The callback is also useful for any combination in which you want to filter out the "falsey" values, except some. (For example, filter every `null` and `false`, etc, leaving only `0`):

```
$filtered = array_filter($originalArray, 'myCallback');
function myCallback($var) {
    return ($var === 0 || $var === '0');
}
```

Third and fourth case are (for our purposes at last) equivalent, and for that all you have to use is the default:

```
$filtered = array_filter($originalArray);
```

Comment: If you want to take out `null` and `false`, but leave 0, you can also use php's built-in `strlen` function as your callback.

Answer (score 11):

```
$a = array(1, '', '', '', 2, '', 3, 4);
$b = array_values(array_filter($a));

print_r($b)
```

Answer (score 11):

For multidimensional array

```
$data = array_map('array_filter', $data);
$data = array_filter($data);
```

Answer (score 10):

I had to do this in order to keep an array value of (string) 0

```
$url = array_filter($data, function ($value) {
  return (!empty($value) || $value === 0 || $value==='0');
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Just want to contribute an alternative to loops...also addressing gaps in keys...

In my case, I wanted to keep sequential array keys when the operation was complete (not just odd numbers, which is what I was staring at. Setting up code to look just for odd keys seemed fragile to me and not future-friendly.)

I was looking for something more like this: http://gotofritz.net/blog/howto/removing-empty-array-elements-php/

The combination of array_filter and array_slice does the trick.

```
$example = array_filter($example);
$example = array_slice($example,0);
```

No idea about efficiencies or benchmarks but it works.

Comment: I think array_values would have the same result as array_slice. That seems more intuitive in terms of reading the code later and understanding what it is doing.

Answer (score 9):

```
function trim_array($Array)
{
    foreach ($Array as $value) {
        if(trim($value) === '') {
            $index = array_search($value, $Array);
            unset($Array[$index]);
        }
    }
    return $Array;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Comment: Why would you not, more simply, declare `$index` in the `foreach()` signature?  This unexplained answer is not performant/optimized/direct.

Answer (score 9):

```
$out_array = array_filter($input_array, function($item) 
{ 
    return !empty($item['key_of_array_to_check_whether_it_is_empty']); 
}
);
```

Answer (score 7):

I use the following script to remove empty elements from an array

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count($Array); $i++)
  {
    if (empty($Array[$i])) unset($Array[$i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$my = ("0"=>" ","1"=>"5","2"=>"6","3"=>" ");   

foreach ($my as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) unset($my[$key]);
}

foreach ($my as $key => $value) {
    echo   $key . ':' . $value . '<br>';
}
```

**output**

> 1:5
>
> 2:6

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
   if (empty($val)) unset($arr[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just one line :
Update (thanks to @suther):

```
$array_without_empty_values = array_filter($array);
```

Comment: don't need your second parameter: $clean_array = array_filter($dirty_array);

Answer (score 3):

use `array_filter` function to remove empty values:

```
$linksArray = array_filter($linksArray);
print_r($linksArray);
```

Comment: He wants to remove *blank strings*, which is not equivalent to empty values.

Answer (score 3):

Remove empty array elements

```php
function removeEmptyElements(&$element)
{
    if (is_array($element)) {
        if ($key = key($element)) {
            $element[$key] = array_filter($element);
        }

        if (count($element) != count($element, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) {
            $element = array_filter(current($element), __FUNCTION__);
        }

        return $element;
    } else {
        return empty($element) ? false : $element;
    }
}

$data = array(
    'horarios' => array(),
    'grupos' => array(
        '1A' => array(
            'Juan' => array(
                'calificaciones' => array(
                    'Matematicas' => 8,
                    'Español' => 5,
                    'Ingles' => 9,
                ),
                'asistencias' => array(
                    'enero' => 20,
                    'febrero' => 10,
                    'marzo' => '',
                )
            ),
            'Damian' => array(
                'calificaciones' => array(
                    'Matematicas' => 10,
                    'Español' => '',
                    'Ingles' => 9,
                ),
                'asistencias' => array(
                    'enero' => 20,
                    'febrero' => '',
                    'marzo' => 5,
                )
            ),
        ),
        '1B' => array(
            'Mariana' => array(
                'calificaciones' => array(
                    'Matematicas' => null,
                    'Español' => 7,
                    'Ingles' => 9,
                ),
                'asistencias' => array(
                    'enero' => null,
                    'febrero' => 5,
                    'marzo' => 5,
                )
            ),
        ),
    )
);

$data = array_filter($data, 'removeEmptyElements');
var_dump($data);
```

¡it works!

Answer (score 3):

As per your method, you can just catch those elements in an another array and use that one like follows,

```
foreach($linksArray as $link){
   if(!empty($link)){
      $new_arr[] = $link
   }
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) is much more suitable here

```
$linksArray = array('name', '        ', '  342', '0', 0.0, null, '', false);

array_walk($linksArray, function(&$v, $k) use (&$linksArray){
    $v = trim($v);
    if ($v == '')
        unset($linksArray[$k]);
});
print_r($linksArray);
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [2] => 342
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

- We made sure that empty values are removed even if the user adds more than one space
- We also trimmed empty spaces from the valid values
- Finally, only (null), (Boolean False) and ('') will be considered empty strings

*As for `False` it's ok to remove it, because AFAIK the user can't submit boolean values.*

Answer (score 1):

With these types of things, it's much better to be explicit about what you want and do not want.

It will help the next guy to not get caught by surprise at the behaviour of `array_filter()` without a callback. For example, I ended up on this question because I forgot if `array_filter()` removes `NULL` or not. I wasted time when I could have just used the solution below and had my answer.

Also, the logic is language angnostic in the sense that the code can be copied into another language without having to under stand the behaviour of a php function like `array_filter` when no callback is passed.

In my solution, it is clear at glance as to what is happening. Remove a conditional to keep something or add a new condition to filter additional values.

Disregard the actual use of `array_filter()` since I am just passing it a custom callback - you could go ahead and extract that out to its own function if you wanted. I am just using it as sugar for a `foreach` loop.

```
<?php

$xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, "0", "", false, null];

$xs = array_filter($xs, function($x) {
    if ($x === null) { return false; }
    if ($x === false) { return false; }
    if ($x === "") { return false; }
    if ($x === "0") { return false; }
    return true;
});

$xs = array_values($xs); // reindex array   

echo "<pre>";
var_export($xs);
```

Another benefit of this approach is that you can break apart the filtering predicates into an abstract function that filters a single value per array and build up to a composable solution.

See this example and the inline comments for the output.

```php
<?php

/**
 * @param string $valueToFilter
 *
 * @return \Closure A function that expects a 1d array and returns an array
 *                  filtered of values matching $valueToFilter.
 */
function filterValue($valueToFilter)
{
    return function($xs) use ($valueToFilter) {
        return array_filter($xs, function($x) use ($valueToFilter) {
            return $x !== $valueToFilter;
        });
    };
}

// partially applied functions that each expect a 1d array of values
$filterNull = filterValue(null);
$filterFalse = filterValue(false);
$filterZeroString = filterValue("0");
$filterEmptyString = filterValue("");

$xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, null, false, "0", ""];

$xs = $filterNull($xs);        //=> [0, 1, 2, 3, false, "0", ""]
$xs = $filterFalse($xs);       //=> [0, 1, 2, 3, "0", ""]
$xs = $filterZeroString($xs);  //=> [0, 1, 2, 3, ""]
$xs = $filterEmptyString($xs); //=> [0, 1, 2, 3]

echo "<pre>";
var_export($xs); //=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now you can dynamically create a function called `filterer()` using `pipe()` that will apply these partially applied functions for you.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Supply between 1..n functions each with an arity of 1 (that is, accepts
 * one and only one argument). Versions prior to php 5.6 do not have the
 * variadic operator `...` and as such require the use of `func_get_args()` to
 * obtain the comma-delimited list of expressions provided via the argument
 * list on function call.
 *
 * Example - Call the function `pipe()` like:
 *
 *   pipe ($addOne, $multiplyByTwo);
 *
 * @return closure
 */
function pipe()
{
    $functions = func_get_args(); // an array of callable functions [$addOne, $multiplyByTwo]
    return function ($initialAccumulator) use ($functions) { // return a function with an arity of 1
        return array_reduce( // chain the supplied `$arg` value through each function in the list of functions
            $functions, // an array of functions to reduce over the supplied `$arg` value
            function ($accumulator, $currFn) { // the reducer (a reducing function)
                return $currFn($accumulator);
            },
            $initialAccumulator
        );
    };
}

/**
 * @param string $valueToFilter
 *
 * @return \Closure A function that expects a 1d array and returns an array
 *                  filtered of values matching $valueToFilter.
 */
function filterValue($valueToFilter)
{
    return function($xs) use ($valueToFilter) {
        return array_filter($xs, function($x) use ($valueToFilter) {
            return $x !== $valueToFilter;
        });
    };
}

$filterer = pipe(
    filterValue(null),
    filterValue(false),
    filterValue("0"),
    filterValue("")
);

$xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, null, false, "0", ""];
$xs = $filterer($xs);

echo "<pre>";
var_export($xs); //=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this ** 
**Example**

```
$or = array(
        'PersonalInformation.first_name' => $this->request->data['User']['first_name'],
        'PersonalInformation.last_name' => $this->request->data['User']['last_name'],
        'PersonalInformation.primary_phone' => $this->request->data['User']['primary_phone'],
        'PersonalInformation.dob' => $this->request->data['User']['dob'],
        'User.email' => $this->request->data['User']['email'],
    );



 $or = array_filter($or);

    $condition = array(
        'User.role' => array('U', 'P'),
        'User.user_status' => array('active', 'lead', 'inactive'),
        'OR' => $or
    );
```

Comment: what is this? there are tons of other very relevant answers. What are you adding here?

Comment: check out the url what was the  question here!!/*remove empty array element*/