# How to count non-empty entries in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

Consider:

```
[name] => Array ( [1] => name#1
                  [2] => name#2
                  [3] => name#3
                  [4] => name#4
                  [5] =>
                  [6] =>
                  [7] =>
                  [8] =>
                  [9] =>
                )


$name = $_POST['name']
```

I want the result to be `4`.

```
count ($name) = 9
count (isset($name)) = 1
count (!empty($name)) = 1
```

I would think that last one would accomplish what I need, but it is not (the empty entries are from unfilled inputs on the form).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to only keep the values that are “truthy” in the array, like this:

```
array_filter($array);
```

If you explicitly want only non-`empty`, or if your filter function is more complex:

```
array_filter($array, function($x) { return !empty($x); });
# function(){} only works in in php >5.3, otherwise use create_function
```

So, to count only non-empty items, the same way as if you called `empty(item)` on each of them:

```
count(array_filter($array, function($x) { return !empty($x); }));
```

However, as `empty()` is only a shorthand for 'variable is set and the value is truthy', you don't really gain anything from that, because if your array contains values such as `FALSE` or `"0"`, those would count as empty as well, same as with the plain call to `array_filter`.

The better way is to be explicit about what you want to count, e.g. if you want to exclude empty strings only, then use:

```php
array_filter($array, function($x) { return ($x !== ""); });
```

Comment: `empty()` is most appropriately used when checking for two possibilities: 1. a variable is not declared or 2. a variable contains a falsey value.  In this case, there is no reason to check if `$x` is undeclared because it is guaranteed to be declared by the anonymous function.  Instead a simple `return $x;` will suffice -- that is, if not using the most simple `array_filter($array)` technique.

Comment: Indeed, using `empty()` here makes little sense because an array of values will be passed anyway, but the explicit way abstracts better to other cases of array filtering and counting.

Answer (score 30):

```
count(array_filter($name));
```

Comment: Note that this does not just return empty elements but every element that’s value is [equal to `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (i.e. `""`, `null`, `0`, `false`, `"0"`).

Comment: I'd better offset Gumbo's warning and make sure that researchers (and voters) are aware that moeffju's answer will perform identically to this one because `empty()` performs with the same greedy rules as `array_filter()` without a callback.

Answer (score 5):

**Possible Solution:** First you need to remove empty/null, false and zero values from an array and then count remaining values of an array

If you no need to remove zero values from an array, but remove null and false values

```
count(array_filter($arrayName, 'strlen'));
//"strlen" use as second parameter if you no need to remove zero '0' values
```

if you need to remove zero, null and false values from an array

```
count(array_filter($arrayName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple calculation function:

```
function non_empty(array $a) {
    return array_sum(array_map(function($b) {return empty($b) ? 0 : 1;}, $a));
}
```

This will preserve array indexes if your form handling function needs them, like when you're associating the third input on name to the third value of another input set, and there are empty inputs in between them.

Answer (score 0):

**The easyest aproach is to use** `count()` **and** `array_filter()` **functions** (eventually with an additional callback within `array_filter()` when we need type compatibility checking, but when the result of default `empty()` function is enough for us we don't need it).

**However, we can also achieve that by using the** `array_reduce()` **function**, and this approach is slightly more optimal in terms of computational complexity:

```
$initial = 0;
$count = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry += empty($item) ? 0 : 1;
    return $carry;
}, $initial);
```

The `$count` variable counts all non-empty items in the array `$arr`.

Note that, the condition can be changed if someone wishes, e.g. instead of `empty($item)` we can use a stronger condition `$item === ''`, etc.

When the array `$arr` is empty, `$initial` is returned.

Comment: `$carry += !empty($item);` also works because the boolean return will be converted to a 1 or a 0 during addition.  However, I would never call `empty()` when I know a variable is guaranteed to exist.  In other words, you could use `$carry += (bool)$item;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @mickmackusa. Of course, your examples are correct, but I prefer to use the ternary (`?:`) operator instead of implicitly casting on an integer. I was curious that you prefer to cast a variable to be boolean than use `empty()` on that variable when guaranteed. Why? Does it have to do with performance?

Comment: When I can eliminate iterated function calls I often do so.  Because for general-use we don't know how many iterations there will be, there may be only 5 or there could be 100,000.  Ternary is fine too.  `$carry += $item ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @mickmackusa. I look at these functions as an *O(1)* operation. But I agree that executing a function, even such a simple and built-in one, may involve additional jumps in memory to the definition of the function.

Comment: BTW @mickmackusa: Of course, the answer's code example loop is the *O(n)* type independent of the `empty()` function usage.