# Exclude null values from COUNT in array

Tags: php

How can I exclude null values from a count on an array?
since count always includes null values in the counting!

Comment: PHP nulls are not the same as SQL nulls. You'll have to roll your own `my_count()` function to account for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to count non-empty entries in php array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array)

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($array as $index=>$value) {
    if($value === null) unset($array[$index]);
}
echo count($array);
```

---

Or if you don't want to modify the array:

```
function myCount($arr)  {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($arr as $index=>$value) {
        if($value !== null) $count++;
    }
    return $count;    
}

echo myCount($array);
```

Comment: Still `in` instead of `as`. And you don't need `$index=>` in the second (arguably preferable) version.

Comment: @phihag oops, that was accidental... Fixed that.

Comment: I believe that the 'foreach' statement in the function should read: foreach($arr as $index=>$value). 

Sadly SO doesn't allow others to submit edits which are less than 6 characters or I'd have corrected it myself ;-)

Comment: @ChayaCooper I am not sure how that is any different from the current answer.

Comment: oh. I see. I will fix @ChayaCooper

Answer (score 4):

```
function count_nonnull($a) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($a as $elt) {
        if (!is_null($elt)) {
            $total++;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see some braces in there.

Answer (score 4):

```
count(array_filter($array, function($x) {return !is_null($x); })
```

Comment: Elegant solution, but this constructs a temporary list in memory. Still waiting for `itertools.ifilter` ;)

Comment: @phihag Thanks. Yes, if you're on a limited shared memory host or have a very large array to go through, the above implementation may not be the most efficient. Edit: Thanks for editing the code for fix.

Comment: Or even `count($array) - count(array_filter($array, 'is_null'))`.  Better to use built-in than to declare your own anonymous function :-)

Answer (score 1):

// **easiest way** 
echo count(array_filter($array));
[instructions](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-remove-empty-values-from-an-array-in-php.php)

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739