# Count number of non-empty items in array?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to count non-empty entries in php array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array)

I want to count the number of keys in an array that aren't empty/null.

```
EG:
array(1>'asdf',2>'fdas',3>'');

count($array) would return 3, I want a function that returns 2 as 3 is empty
```

Are there any php built in functions to do this? How can it be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789083/exclude-null-values-from-count-in-array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array

Comment: Learn [PHP's array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
count(array_filter($array));
```

> array array_filter ( array $input [, callable $callback = "" ] )
>
> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see
>   converting to boolean) will be removed.