# How to remove null values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => [2] => 3 [3] => )

i want to remove null values from this and the result should be like this

Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3) 
i don't want to remove 0 value from array.

Comment: http://www.php.net/array_filter with custom callback.

Comment: on php.net look up array filter

Comment: simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Answer (score 84):

this will do the trick:

```
array_filter($arr, static function($var){return $var !== null;} );
```

Code Example: https://3v4l.org/jtQa2

---

for older versions (php<5.3):

```
function is_not_null ($var) { return !is_null($var); }
$filtered = array_filter($arr, 'is_not_null');
```

Code Example: http://3v4l.org/CKrYO

Comment: Only works in newer versions, but this is way better than the strange strlen thing.

Comment: For older versions one can predeclare the function used.

Comment: added code example for older phpVersions

Comment: You can exclude the second param entirely; `array_filter($arr);` will remove `null` by default.

Comment: @AlexP nope, you are wrong.
as seen on  https://3v4l.org/Y9KCX your solution would remove everything that is `empty()` - not just NULL.

Comment: @AlexP: a string '0' for instance will be removed, if you dismiss filter function.

Comment: Micro optimizations: `array_filter($data, static function($var){return $var !== null;} )`

Answer (score 29):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which will get rid of the null empty values from the array

```
print_r(array_filter($arr, 'strlen'));
```

Comment: This does not work.
$ php -r "var_dump(array_filter([0, null, false, 'hi', ''], 'strlen'));"
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(0)
  [3] =>
  string(2) "hi"
}

Comment: this also removes '0', false, or falsey values in general might have forgotten others.

Comment: this will include '' which is not null

Comment: You can even do $arr = array_filter($arr); with no callback and it will still remove empty items.

Comment: From PHP8.1 this is no longer a good technique because it will generate Deprecations. `Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated`

Answer (score 6):

You can just loop through it.

```
<?php 
foreach ($array as $i=>$row) {
    if ($row === null)
       unset($array[$i]);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/jFTWZnPT)

If you want to reindex the array to remove gaps between keys, you can just use a new array:

```
<?php
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if ($row !== null)
       $array2[] = $row;
}
$array = $array2;
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/7Pcrhoe0)

Answer (score 4):

You are in a world of trouble now, because it is not too easy to distinguish null from 0 from false from "" from 0.0. But don't worry, it is solvable:

```
 $result = array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );
```

Which is horrible by itself, but seems to work.

EDIT:

This is bad advice, because the trick leans on a strange corner case:

- strlen(0) will be strlen("0") -> 1, thus  true
- strlen(NULL) will be strlen("")->0, thus false
- strlen("") will be strlen(("")->0, thus false 
  etc.

The way you should do it is something like this:

```
 $my_array = array(2, "a", null, 2.5, NULL, 0, "", 8);

 function is_notnull($v) {
    return !is_null($v);
  }

 print_r(array_filter($my_array, "is_notnull"));
```

This is well readable.

Comment: From PHP8.1 `strlen` is no longer a good technique because it will generate Deprecations. `Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$arr = array( 0 => 0, 1=>null, 2=>3, 3=>null); 
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {
    if ($val === null)
       unset($arr[$key]);
}
$new_arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($new_arr);
?>
```

Out put:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**simply**

```
$keys=array_keys($yourArray,NULL);
if(!empty($keys))
{
foreach($keys as $key)
{
unset($yourArray[$key]);
}
}
var_dump($yourarray);
```