# How to remove `null` result when using array_unique?

Tags: php, arrays, null, array-filter, array-unique

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
$subregion = [
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "8",
        "subregion_name" => "NORTH_AMERICA",
        "subregion_abbr" => "US"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "9",
        "subregion_name" => "NORTH_AMERICA",
        "subregion_abbr" => "CA"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "6",
        "subregion_name" => "WE",
        "subregion_abbr" => "South"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "0",
        "subregion_name" => null,
        "subregion_abbr" => null
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "5",
        "subregion_name" => "WE",
        "subregion_abbr" => "North"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "0",
        "subregion_name" => null,
        "subregion_abbr" => null
    ]
];
```

I want to unique that array by its values so I have test the following (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)):

```
$subregion = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $subregion)));
$subregion = array_intersect_key($subregion, array_unique(array_map('serialize', $subregion)));
$subregion_unique = array_unique($subregion, SORT_REGULAR);
```

All of them work (tried one by one) and produces the same output:

```
$subregion = [
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "8",
        "subregion_name" => "NORTH_AMERICA",
        "subregion_abbr" => "US"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "9",
        "subregion_name" => "NORTH_AMERICA",
        "subregion_abbr" => "CA"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "6",
        "subregion_name" => "WE",
        "subregion_abbr" => "South"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "5",
        "subregion_name" => "WE",
        "subregion_abbr" => "North"
    ],
    [
        "subregion_id"   => "0",
        "subregion_name" => null,
        "subregion_abbr" => null
    ]
];
```

I want to get rid of the `null` values on the array because them should not be there. So I have tried this other workaround ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20676918/719427)):

```
private function is_not_null($var)
{
    return !is_null($var);
}

$unique = array_filter($subregion_unique, 'is_not_null');
```

But surprise the output of `$unique` is exactly the same as before, why? What I am missing here?

**NOTE** I forgot to mention that should be compatible with PHP 5.3.10+

**Update: test1**

Following @abracadaver instructions this is what I've tried:

```
$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $subregion)));
$unique = array_map(function($v) { return array_filter($v, 'is_not_null'); }, $unique);
```

I have changed the function `is_not_null($var)` above to return result in this way:

```
return null !== $var;
```

The result is an array with `null` values.

PS: Maybe the title is not accurate and the post is tempted to be closed or marked as duplicate, if so please suggest me a better title or change by yourself if you can.

Comment: `$subregion_unique` is? Anyway, the problem is that you are not accessing your `2-Dimensional array` properly in the function `is_not_null`

Comment: @Aaron the last line on my test `$subregion_unique = array_unique($subregion, SORT_REGULAR);`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447923/how-to-filter-a-two-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: @Aaron is not what I am doing already at `is_not_null()` ?

Comment: Nope. You need to check something like `!is_null($var['property'])` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have all that code.  This one line gets a unique array:

```
$unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $subregion)));
```

Then to filter out the `null` with your current function:

```
$unique = array_map(function($v) { return array_filter($v, 'is_not_null'); }, $unique);
```

If you don't care if the `0` is removed then it's even shorter and you don't need your function:

```
$unique = array_map(function($v) { return array_filter($v); }, $unique);
```

Then you know you'll have an empty child array, so you can filter it:

```
$unique = array_filter($unique);
```

The `SORT_REGULAR` makes no difference here, but for when it may, or if you need a different flag, you would just add it in the above `array_unique()`:

```
$unique = array_map("unserialize",
                    array_unique(array_map("serialize", $subregion), SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: Check my **Update: test1** in OP, isn't working for me.

Comment: Probably need a new question, it obviously works https://3v4l.org/dQkaE

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you get rid off the null:

```
foreach($subregion_unique as $key => $item) {
    foreach($item as $itemKey => $value) {
        if($value === null) {
            unset($subregion_unique[$key][$itemKey];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

php >=5.3 
use it in this way

```
$unique = array_map(function($a){
                 return array_filter($a); 
              },$subregion);
```

to filter each subarray

or just

```
foreach($subregion as &$a){
   $a=array_filter($a);
}
```

if the "subregion_id"="0" can be skipped

Comment: Removes `"0"` as well.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Good Point, but the entry with `"0"` has no value, so it can be removed. Or is Id=0 a real id ;)

Comment: Dunno.  Based on the key `subregion_id` I assumed it might be important.

Comment: @JOUM is this compatible with PHP 5.3.10+? I forgot to mention that on the OP

Comment: Anonymous functions available since 5.3.0.

Comment: @JOUM this one is not working for me, is returning the same array with several empty positions on the array, maybe I am skipping something, can you update the answer with the whole example?