# How to filter out blank values from an array in PHP & Reindex the array

Tags: php, arrays

I am printing out the values using `print_r($_POST["prod_sizes"]);`

```
print_r($_POST["prod_sizes"]);
```

So i get output like this => `dsf,,thisnajndk,faklsf,klam,flkamlkd,mklmd,l,,adad`

After that i use this code:

```
$sizes = strip_tags(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9,]/i', '', $_POST["prod_sizes"]));
$var = explode(',', $sizes);
print_r($var);
```

I get output like

```
Array
(
  [0] => dsf
  [1] => 
  [2] => thisnajndk
  [3] => faklsf
  [4] => klam
  [5] => flkamlkd
  [6] => mklmd
  [7] => l
  [8] => 
  [9] => adad
)
```

As from the above output we can see that there are some blank values in an array. How to remove those blank values?

Comment: `array_filter()` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code from this line => `$var = explode(',', $sizes);` & add this:

```
$var = array_filter(explode(',', $sizes));
$reindexed = array();

foreach ($var as $row)
    {
        if ($row !== null)
           $reindexed[] = $row;
    }

print_r($reindexed);
exit();
```

**Let's See The Explaination of the code now**

1.) This is 1st reference link from where i took the idea to filer but ass you prnt the array you will see that the array indexes are jumbled => [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

```
$var = array_filter(explode(',', $sizes));
$reindexed = array();
```

so we create a new variables `reindexed` as an array to store the reindexed array value

2.) To remove the jumbled array index and reindex the array i took refernce from this link => [How to remove null values from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676771/how-to-remove-null-values-from-an-array)

```
$reindexed = array();

foreach ($var as $row)
    {
        if ($row !== null)
           $reindexed[] = $row;
    }

print_r($reindexed);
```

Comment: This is an overly complicated way to do something, especially considering PHP already has built in functionality to do this.

Comment: @JohnConde even i am new to PHP i just made the code according to my logic and provided, your code is super perfect as it is very clean and easy

Answer (score 5):

PHP's built in [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will do this for you:

```
$sizes = array_filter($sizes);
```

Keep in mind that any values are [equate to false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) will also be filtered out. So if zero and null is a valid value you will need to write your own callback to filter by.

If you also want to re-index the keys just use [`array_values()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the result:

```
$sizes = array_values(array_filter($sizes));
```

Comment: I also wanted to re-index the array

Comment: Then just `array_values()` on the result. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the best way**:

```
# Array
$array = array('tomato', '', 'apple', 'melon', 'cherry', '', '', 'banana');
```

that returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => 
    [2] => apple
    [3] => melon
    [4] => cherry
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => banana
)
```

by doing this

```
$array = array_values(array_filter($array));
```

you get this

```
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => apple
    [2] => melon
    [3] => cherry
    [4] => banana
)
```

**Explanation**

`array_values()` : Returns the values of the input array and indexes numerically.

`array_filter()` : Filters the elements of an array with a user-defined function (UDF **If none is provided**, **all entries in the input table valued FALSE will be deleted**.)

Comment: Why repeat John Conde's advice???