# array count non empty values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that post this values:

> actusr    **16**
>
> crediti[0] **CD000001125**
> crediti[1] **CD000001126**
> crediti[2] **CD000001127**
>
> garanzia[0] **11556493.48**
> garanzia[1]
> garanzia[2]
>
> soff_for **SF000000179**
>
> soff_who **SF000000002**
>
> tipo_gar[0] **1**
> tipo_gar[1]
> tipo_gar[2]

I'd like to count how many items in `tipo_gar` array have a non empty value.
I can do it via foreach:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($_POST['tipo_gar'] as $to_count){
    if($to_count != ''){
        $count=$count+1;
    }
}
```

but I guess there is a built-in php functionality I am not aware of that will do the trick saving me some lines of code.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array possible duplicate ;)

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count non-empty value using [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). `array_filter` can only keep the values that are non-empty in the array.

```
count(array_filter($_POST['tipo_gar']));
```

Comment: ok, so I build an array with only non empty items and then count it. Smart! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: will be back when I can accept your answer :)