# How can I check whether only one out of three variables is not empty?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, var

I have three variables:

```
$var1
$var2
$var3
```

I'm actually looking for the best way to check if **only one** of these three variables is not empty and the **two others** are empty.

Is that possible to do this with one `if` only? If not, then what's the best way?

The variables all contain text.

Comment: First need to `trim` all `var`

   ` $var1 = trim($var1);
    $var2 = trim($var2);
    $var3 = trim($var3);`
then check it.

Comment: Can you let us know what is the data type of the variable?

Comment: datatype is text.

Comment: I have answered the question. I guess else part in my answer should work for you.

Comment: As far as I know, "text" is not a PHP datatype; "string" is. The distinction is not merely arbitrary. Strings are merely arrays of bytes, while text is abstract characters. (PHP's `mbstring` functions blur the distinction.)

Comment: A PHP question in the HNQ (Hot Network Questions)? What a time to be alive! :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus and it's not PHP OOP (phpoop) as well!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can convert variable into array and exclude empty variables using `array_filter()`. Then use `count()` after the filter.

```
if(count(array_filter(array($var1,$var2,$var3)))==1){
  //only 1 variable is not empty
}
```

Check [Fiddle link](https://eval.in/642080)

Comment: you say //only 1 variable is empty. but i want only one NOT EMPTY. :)

Comment: down vote for using `compact` , `[$var1,$var2,$var3]`  same result

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me....i wrote : if(count(array_filter(compact($var1,$var2,$var3)))==1){ what's the problem ?

Comment: @cske : Thank you very much !!

Comment: @cetipabo, if you like this answer please mark as correct.

Comment: @cske, I have made changes in answer as per you noticed for `compact`, if you like then please up vote it please.

Comment: By which reason I get down vote...because based on performance of memory and execution time latest version of PHP perform this code faster

Answer (score 25):

Booleans return 0 and 1 with array_sum()

```
if (array_sum(array(empty($var1), empty($var2), empty($var3))) == 1)
{
    echo "one is empty" ;
}
```

ETA:
This is a simpler way:

```
if (!empty($var1) + !empty($var2) + !empty($var3) == 1) {
    echo "1 is not empty" ;
}
```

ETA 2: We don't need the negative signs

```
if (empty($var1) + empty($var2) + empty($var3) == 2) {
    echo "1 is not empty" ;
}
```

Comment: If you want to make 100% sure it's an integer without casting every single variable, use like this:  `(0 + empty($var1) + empty($var2) + ...)`

Comment: @DanFromGermany `0 +` is not necessary because you don't add variables but result from the function call `empty()` which is `0` or `1`

Comment: @DominiqueLorre the result from `empty()` is `true` or `false`, not 1 or 0. `boolean` evaluates to `integer` in arithmetic operations but this is not for granted 100% in all situations in every version. I know it's not necessary. What I want to say is, this is a method of an explicit `cast`. Like `0.0 + integer` will translate to `0.0 + (float)integer` and evaluate to `float` finally.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, in that case, I think Hanky Panky's answer is better. If true he uses 0 and if false he uses 1, so that's inverted, but the result is the same and you do not cast anything. He only uses integers.

Answer (score 10):

```
$counter=0;
$counter+= empty($var1) ? 0:1;
$counter+= empty($var2) ? 0:1;
$counter+= empty($var3) ? 0:1;

if($counter==1)
   echo "Exactly 2 are empty";
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/641962)**

Or you can simply do

```
var_dump(count(array_filter(array($var1,$var2,$var3)))==1);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/641979)**

Comment: Do you mean "Exactly 1 is empty"

Comment: Nope, i exactly mean exactly 2 are empty

Comment: @cetipabo if you are using this one, shouldn't it be marked as the answer?

Answer (score 7):

I'd use `XOR` ([exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)) for this, because it's intended for this purpose, so using a dirty workaround with an array is not as easy to understand.

```
if (!(!empty($var1) && !empty($var2) && !empty($var3)) && (!empty($var1) ^ !empty($var2) ^ !empty($var3))) {
    echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
}
```

---

And it's about 25% faster than the accepted answer.

```
$before = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    $var1 = 'Hello';
    $var2 = '';
    $var3 = '';

    if (!(!empty($var1) && !empty($var2) && !empty($var3)) && (!empty($var1) ^ !empty($var2) ^ !empty($var3))) {
        echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
    }

    $var4 = '';
    $var5 = '';
    $var6 = '';

    if (!(!empty($var4) && !empty($var5) && !empty($var6)) && (!empty($var4) ^ !empty($var5) ^ !empty($var6))) {
        echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
    }

    $var7 = 'Hello';
    $var8 = 'World';
    $var9 = '!';

    if (!(!empty($var7) && !empty($var8) && !empty($var9)) && (!empty($var7) ^ !empty($var8) ^ !empty($var9))) {
        echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
    }
}

$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec for XOR\n";

// 3.2943892478943E-6 sec for XOR

$before = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    $var1 = 'Hello';
    $var2 = '';
    $var3 = '';

    if (count(array_filter(array($var1, $var2, $var3))) == 1) {
        echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
    }

    $var4 = '';
    $var5 = '';
    $var6 = '';

    if (count(array_filter(array($var4, $var5, $var6))) == 1) {
        echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
    }

    $var7 = 'Hello';
    $var8 = 'World';
    $var9 = '';

    if (count(array_filter(array($var7, $var8, $var9))) == 1) {
        echo "Only one string is not empty\n";
    }
}
$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec for Arrays\n";

// 4.3078589439392E-6 sec for Arrays
```

---

*I had to update the answer because the name "exclusive or" is somewhat misleading in context of more than two expressions. Of course all commenters are right, and exclusive or is a binary operation therefore resolving from left to right. `1 ^ 1 ^ 1 == 1` resolves to `0 ^ 1 == 1` and is therefore `true`. Exclusive or does actually look for an odd number of trues.

I updated my answer with an easy-to-read workaround, but this definitely doesn't satisfy me and I have to admin that I resolved a huge misconception of boolean operators in my mind. The last time was a wrong assumption of `AND` and `OR` being resolved from left to right rather than first `AND` then `OR`.*

Comment: Strange, there was another answer with xor but it disappeared. Oh well, you get the +1

Comment: I secretly hacked SO to delete it, so I could earn all the reputation. Please don't tell anyone. It's our little secret.

Comment: @Kevin I tested it multiple times and it seems to work. What's the problem? I'm curious wether it's related to a specific PHP version.

Comment: This should detect if there are even number of empty variables, not if there are exactly 2.

Comment: @hyde What do you mean? The `XOR`-construct only returns `true` if one and **exactly** one of the statements is `true`, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: @FabioPoloni: Try with three non-empty variables. `1 ^ 1 ^ 1 == 1`

Comment: @FabioPoloni did you test it with all three variables being set to something?

Comment: @FabioPoloni That is not a ternary operaation. XOR is between two values, so you have 2 XOR operations there, not 1 with 3 operands.

Comment: Of course you are all right. And this is probably the reason the first post using exclusive or disappeared.

Comment: @Andrew there can only be an odd number of XOR answers to this question.

Comment: How did you account for the overhead of the loop (and possibly other overhead)? What about a possible warming up period? You also ought to state on what system it was tested on, including relevant specifications.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The absolute numbers provided are completely useless because of the factors you mentioned. The main thing I wanted to know is which one is faster, so the used system as well as the other overhead is irrelevant because it's the same.

Comment: The original XOR answers was mine, i deleted it because it simply does not work because `true ^ true ^ true` will result as `true` due to `true & true` being `false` and `false ^ true` being true, no point in keeping up an answer which gives wrong results and taken that i kept getting upvotes i deleted it, i did not want to spread false information :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
if (($var1 !== '' && $var2 == '' && $var3 == '') ||
    ($var2 !== '' && $var1 == '' && $var3 == '')  ||
    ($var3 !== '' && $var1 == '' && $var2 == '')) {
    echo 'variable is empty';
}
```

Comment: "I'm actually looking for the best way to check if only one of these 3 var is not empty and the 2 others are empty."

Comment: OP has 3 variables, only 1 is allowed to be empty. Your answer is like you have 3 variables and 2 of them are allowed to be empty.

Comment: As per OP's query he was asking for a solution with one IF only. I have provided the same. This doesn't mean that my solution is incorrect.

Comment: it does mean it is incorrect, you can have 3 empty values and it wil stil return true

Comment: I guess OP had edited the question later on, it seems it was incorrect in the inital stage. Since there are more such answers similar to mine.

Comment: in your IF you say the same thing 3 times, just in a different order...so you don't do 3 tests, but only 1. Not sure i'm clear...

Comment: @cetipabo It's not doing the same thing 3 times. It's actually checking 3 different things. It's checking if var1 is the only non-empty variable, OR var2 is the only non-empty variable, OR var 3 is the only non-empty variable. So this answer is correct. It is probably the most straight-forward way to check that ONLY ONE variable is non-empty.

Comment: If you use the `!==` operator for the non-empty test, should you not be using `===` for the empty test? I am thinking that `empty(...)` would probably be safer if the variable can be strings or arrays.

Comment: @Alexis Wilke Thanks for the update, I never thought about it before. Will surely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation where you should use arrays. You now only have 3 values, but what if you need 4? You'll need to change all your code!

```
$var = array();
$var[] = 'abc';
$var[] = '';
$var[] = 0;

// will return 1, empty values, false or 0 (falsy values) will not get counted:
echo count(array_filter($var)).' values found';
if( count(array_filter($var))==1 ){ echo 'exactly one value set'; }
```

If you do need to chek zero's or empty strings [you can use other methods to count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422889/how-to-count-non-empty-entries-in-php-array). The main principle of this code is that if you add more values, the logic itself doesn't need changing.

Comment: Haha, the answer in the link to the other methods. Fixed it, thatnks

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise XOR is great for this:

```
$var1 ^ $var2 ^ $var3
```

You *might* have trouble if the variables don't cast to boolean easily, in which case you'd need to do `empty($var)` on each of them.

Boom. Zero `if`s.

**Update**

Oops, if they are *all* not empty, true ^ true ^ true == true

You'll need to check against all of them being true:

```
($var1 ^ $var2 ^ $var3) && !($var1 && $var2 && $var3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$temp_array = array($var1,$var2,$var3);
$temp_count = count(array_filter($temp_array, 'strlen'));
if($temp_count ==1){
    echo "1 variable is not empty";
}
else
{
    echo "total empty variable  is = ".$temp_count;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/17k7K)**

Comment: OP has 3 variables, only 1 is allowed to be empty. Your answer is like you have 3 variables and 2 of them are allowed to be empty.