# php remove "empty" values in array

Tags: php

I'm trying to clean an array from empty values by using the following function:

```
function remove_empty_cells($data)
{
    $findthis = array("/\r\n/u", "/\n/u", "/\r/u", "/\s+/u", "~\x{00a0}~");
    for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++)
    {
        $data[$i] = preg_replace($findthis, " ", $data[$i]);
        $data[$i] = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars($data[$i], ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8'));
        if (empty($data[$i]) ||
            mb_strlen($data[$i]) < strlen($data[$i]) ||
            is_null($data[$i]) ||
            $data[$i] = " " ||
            $data[$i] = "" ||
            $data[$i] == "0")
        {
             array_splice($data, $i, 1);
        };//end if
    };//end for
    return $data;
};//end func
```

The empty values don't go away, I fail to identify them..

the data:

```
array (
  0 => '
',
  1 => 'BEGIN:VCARD 
',
  2 => '
',
  3 => '
',
  4 => '
',
  5 => '
',
  6 => '
',
  7 => 'VERSION:2.1 
',
```

...
might be some encoding problem or something.. it doesnt look like multibyte characters..
the result i get is:

```
array (
  0 => 'BEGIN:VCARD 
',
  1 => '
',
  2 => '
',
  3 => 'VERSION:2.1 
',
```

...

Comment: please post your data

Comment: @LeoTahk Check the solution I provided below

Comment: yes, the trim worked, thanks for pointing it out. marked as answered. simple array_filter had no effect.

Comment: simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739

Comment: why doesn't `\x{00a0}` get a unicode flag too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the PHP function `array_filter()` to remove the empty values with callback function as below

```
<?php
    $array = array("sampe1", "\n  ", "   ", "sample2", null, "sample4", "rajesh", "suresh", "test", "");

    $result = array_filter($array, function($v){
       return trim($v);
    });

    var_dump($result);

    $res = array_slice($result);

    var_dump($res);
?>
```

This will print out:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "sampe1" [3]=> string(7) "sample2" [5]=> string(7) "sample4" [6]=> string(6) "rajesh" [7]=> string(6) "suresh" [8]=> string(4) "test" }
```

---

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "sampe1" [1]=> string(7) "sample2" [2]=> string(7) "sample4" [3]=> string(6) "rajesh" [4]=> string(6) "suresh" [5]=> string(4) "test" }
```

> **SYNTAX** - array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] )

Answer (score 12):

You can use the PHP function `array_filter()` to remove the empty values

```
<?php
$array = array("sampe1", "", "sample2", null, "sample4", "rajesh", "suresh", "test", "");
var_dump($array);
echo "<hr/>";
$result = array_filter($array);                 
var_dump($result);
?>
```

This will print out:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(6) "sampe1" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(7) "sample2" [3]=> NULL [4]=> string(7) "sample4" [5]=> string(6) "rajesh" [6]=> string(6) "suresh" [7]=> string(4) "test" [8]=> string(0) "" }
```

---

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "sampe1" [2]=> string(7) "sample2" [4]=> string(7) "sample4" [5]=> string(6) "rajesh" [6]=> string(6) "suresh" [7]=> string(4) "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure what you did in that code of yours but here is something that can remove empty elements from a php array

**Code Snippet**

```
<?php
   $array = array("apple", "", 2, null, -5, "orange", 10, false, "");
   var_dump($array);
   echo "<br>";

   // Filtering the array
   $result = array_filter($array);                 
   var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: I suppose this will not remove values like `"\n\n"` or `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 2):

Removing empty array slots in PHP, leaving holes in the array.

A quick way to remove empty elements from an array is using array_filter without a callback function. This will also remove 0s (zeroes) though.

> $myArray = array_filter( $myArray );

Alternatively, array_diff allows you to decide which elements to keep. The following example will only remove empty strings, but keep 0

> $myArray = array_diff( $myArray, array( '' ) );

Removing empty array slots in PHP, and compacting the array.

Both functions leave ‘gaps’ where the empty entries used to be. You can see it below, where the indices are [1] and [3] and not [0] and [1].

> $myArray = array( 0, 'red', '', 'blue' );
>   print_r( array_filter( $myArray ) );
>   Array
>   (
>     [1] => 'red'
>     [3] => 'blue'
>   )
>
> print_r( array_diff( $myArray, array( '' ) ) );
>   Array
>   (
>    [0] => 0
>    [1] => 'red'
>    [3] => 'blue'
>   )

array_slice can remove those gaps:

> $myArray = array( 0, 'red', '', 'blue' );
>   $myArray = array_filter( $myArray );
>   print_r( array_slice( $myArray, 0 ) );
>   Array
>    (
>    [0] => 'red'
>     [1] => 'blue'
>   )

so now for your cas, Example

> $arr = ['','BEGIN:VCARD','','','','','','VERSION:2.1']; //initial array
>   print_r($arr);
>   $myArray = array_filter( $arr );
>   print_r( array_slice( $myArray, 0 ) );
>
> ### inital output:
>
> Array ( [0] => [1] => BEGIN:VCARD [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => VERSION:2.1 )
>
> ### final ouput :
>
> Array ( [0] => BEGIN:VCARD [1] => VERSION:2.1 )

Comment: i just used $fileContents = array_filter( $fileContents ); print_r( array_slice( $fileContents, 0 ) );     the result is: Array ( [0] => [1] => BEGIN:VCARD [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => VERSION:2.1 .. not removed :/

Comment: $arr = ['','BEGIN:VCARD','','','','','','VERSION:2.1'];
NEXT:
 print_r($arr);
 $myArray = array_filter( $arr );
 print_r( array_slice( $myArray, 0 ) );


inital output:
Array ( [0] => [1] => BEGIN:VCARD [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => VERSION:2.1 ) 

final ouput :

Array ( [0] => BEGIN:VCARD [1] => VERSION:2.1 )

Comment: the working version for my data is: `$array= array_filter($array, function($v){return trim($v);}); $array= array_slice($array, 0 , count($array));`

Comment: simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004034/7186739