# Can't remove empty elements from array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to remove empty elements from an array. I have a $_POST-String which is set to an array by explode(). Then I'am using a loop to remove the empty elements. But that does not work. I also tried array_filter(), but with no succes. Can you help me? See Code below:

```
$cluster = explode("\n", $_POST[$nr]);

     print_r ($cluster);
     echo "<br>";

  for ($i=0 ; $i<=count($cluster);$i++) 
    {
      if ($cluster[$i] == '') 
       {
         unset ( $cluster[$i] );
       }
    }

     print_r ($cluster);
     echo "<br>";
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => Titel1 [1] => Titel2 [2] => Titel3 [3] => [4] => [5] => )

Array ( [0] => Titel1 [1] => Titel2 [2] => Titel3 [3] => [4] => )
```

Comment: we cant really see what you're empty elements are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist that the for loop condition gets evaluated on every run.

That means `count(...)` will be called multiple times and every time the array shrinks.

The correct way to do this is:

```
$test = explode("/","this/is/example///");
print_r($test);
$arrayElements = count($test);
for($i=0;$i<$arrayElements;$i++)
    if(empty($test[$i])
        unset($test[$i]);

print_r($test);
```

An alternative way without an extra variable would be counting backwards:

```
$test = explode("/","this/is/example///");
print_r($test);
for($i=count($test)-1;$i>=0;$i--)
    if(empty($test[$i])
        unset($test[$i]);

print_r($test);
```

Comment: Thanks.

I've now solved this with trim & a while loop

  $i = 0;
  $v = count($cluster);
  while ( $i<$v) {
    if (trim($cluster[$i]) == '') {
    unset ( $cluster[$i] );
    } $i++;
   }

Answer (score 4):

Empty elements can easily be removed with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Example:

```
$array = array('item_1' => 'hello', 'item_2' => '', 'item_3' => 'world', 'item_4' => '');
$array = array_filter($array);
/*
Array
(
    [item_1] => hello
    [item_3] => world
)
*/
```

Comment: @teuneboon: He didn't post the code for that attempt, so it's possible he/she make a mistake.

Comment: cool, i was about to post `array_filter(function($x){return $x;}, $_POST[$nr]);` but i didnt realize there was a 'default' function like that

Comment: if integer 0 is a valid value, then see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements/3654335#3654335. By default array_filter would remove all 0/False/null/''. See this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#example-4111

Answer (score 1):

What if you change:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<=count($cluster);$i++) { if ($cluster[$i] == '') { unset ( $cluster[$i] ); } }
```

to

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<=count($cluster);$i++) { if (trim($cluster[$i]) == '') { unset ( $cluster[$i] ); } }
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Result is with that:
Array ( [0] => Test1 [1] => Test2 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => ) <br/>

Array ( [0] => Test1 [1] => Test2 [5] => )