# Closures or create_function in PHP

Tags: php, callback, closures, anonymous-function

I had made a decision to use closures for my callbacks instead of `create_function` and as such only support PHP > 5.3 mostly due to the increased debugability and also because I assumed (what is it they say about assumption?) that the overhead of the on-the-fly compilation of the `create_function` in my situation would probably offset any extra comparisons and such that had to be made within in the function.

This may well still be the case (for my application) and further testing is required, but I was interested in the output of this (very) simple test, that shows the `create_function` method being more than twice as fast as the closure when it can remove just four conditionals (and concats). Obviously there is no extra processing going on in my test case, and that is where most of the speed will be gained or lost, but in the case where you have little extra processing but a lot of conditionals (that could be removed) and the callback is called enough times I started to think that it may be better to use `create_function`.

However with the obvious similarity between `create_function` and `eval`, I'm wary of it.

So the main question is what are the differences between anonymous functions created with `create_function` and those of closures?

A few specific questions I'm thinking of are, will `create_function` even work when `eval` functionality is disabled? And, I'm sure I read somewhere recently that `create_function` functions will pollute the global (or class) namespace even if declared as inner functions, but closures won't. I can't find the reference to this now, but are either or  both of those statements true?

---

This is the little test I ran:

```
<?php

function foo($a=true, $b=true, $c=true, $d=true)
{
    $inner1 = create_function(
        '', 
        '$r = \''.($a ? 'a' : '').
                  ($b ? 'b' : '').
                  ($c ? 'c' : '').
                  ($d ? 'd' : '').'\';
         return $r;'
    );  


    $inner2 = function() use ($a, $b, $c, $d) 
    {   
        $r = ''; 
        if($a) { $r .= 'a'; }
        if($b) { $r .= 'b'; }
        if($c) { $r .= 'c'; }
        if($d) { $r .= 'd'; };
        return $r; 
    };  


    $time = microtime(true);
    for ($x=0; $x<99999; ++$x)
    {   
        $i1out = $inner1();
    }   
    echo '1:'.(microtime(true)-$time).'<br>';

    $time = microtime(true);
    for ($x=0; $x<99999; ++$x)
    {   
        $i2out = $inner2();
    }   
    echo '2:'.(microtime(true)-$time).'<br>';

    echo var_dump($i1out===$i2out).'<br>';
}

foo();
```

Comment: It should be pretty easy to test in which namespace `create_function`.. creates the functions.. :)

Comment: I would go for closures also. In terms of speed, maybe you should test it with a real world case scenario. I'm not sure why the one should be that much slower, but I would take the 'hit'. Also, does APC make a difference in this case? Are closures cached in the opcode? It might also make a difference.

Comment: Split them up. This question is already ... long.

Comment: @phihag You're right, it is long, so it's done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The construct `function() {..}` is an anonymous function, and this feature is often implemented together with [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). Neither `create_function` nor anonymous functions pollute the global namespace.

Since anonymous functions can access surrounding variables (the closure part), they can, in theory, be slightly slower. On the other hand, if you're using bytecode caching (and if you're not, you are obviously not concerned about performance), I'd expect the "compilation" overhead of anonymous functions to be slightly slower.

However, it is extremely unlikely that the difference between anonymous functions and `create_function` is a source of performance problems. Therefore, I'd choose the more readable form of an anonymous function if you are so fortunate to have a target platform with php>5.3.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by "pollute the global namespace". `create_function` does create a global function, but its name won't conflict with a name that you use for your functions.

Answer (score 2):

`create_function` creates a global function that persists for the rest of the program. `create_function` simply returns the function name (a string), and therefore can have no idea if you still have access to that name stored somewhere somehow or not. Therefore, it can't be "garbage collected", even if you don't have access to the name anymore.

That means that a big problem is if you create a lot of functions using `create_function`, it will cause your program to run out of memory:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  $f = create_function('', '');
  // do stuff

  // don't use $f anywhere after this point
}
```

whereas with anonymous functions, that won't happen (the closure will be garbage collected).