# Search for same value's in php array

Tags: php, file-handling

I have an array that is linked to a text file where I need the information of a students name and student number that has been entered by user input.

```
if (isset ($_POST['stnum']) && isset ($_POST['stname'])) 
    {
        $studentNum = htmlentities ($_POST['stnum']);
        $studentName = htmlentities ($_POST['stname']);
        $DB = fopen ($students, 'r') or die ("$students cannot be opened for reading.");

        while ($record = fgets ($DB) and ! $foundNum and ! $foundName) 
        {
            $studentField = explode ("$$", htmlentities (trim ($record)));

            $foundNum = $studentNum === $studentField[0];
            $foundName = $studentName === $studentField[1];  
        }

        fclose ($DB);

        if ($foundNum && $foundName) 
        {
            echo $studentField[0], $studentField[1];
        }
    }
```

I cannot figure out how to search for the students that have the same name but different student number. And the file is written like this

```
DA-708-3304$$Elizabeth Organ
GB-217-1214$$John Alexander
SE-412-2175$$Odell Thomas
SH-433-3012$$John Saunders
HU-737-1176$$Frederica Elias
DU-941-4244$$Nancy Sauceda
CC-671-5984$$Margaret Coppa
DA-220-7070$$Walter Snyder
HU-658-4475$$Elizabeth Organ
DU-255-9787$$John Saunders
CC-777-8752$$Hubert Green
```

For example If I try searching for `John Saunders` with a student number `DU-255-9787` it doesn't work but `John Saunders` `SH-433-3012` does because it appears first in the file.

Comment: Not an answer but you have a duplicate line before the while block:
"$studentField = explode ("$$", htmlentities (trim ($record)));"

Comment: Yes I did notice that just a couple of minutes after posting, thank you for that though

Comment: Google for "return all array entries similar" ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966490/find-all-array-keys-that-has-same-value

Comment: I am sure you don't need `htmlentities()` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use break within the if condition? When the condition satisfies?

```
 while ($record = fgets ($DB) and ! $foundNum and ! $foundName) {
     $studentField = explode ("$$", htmlentities (trim ($record)));

     if (($studentName === $studentField[1]) &&  empty($studentNum))) {

          /* When only name is entered by user. So, the user whose number appears first in the list should be printed. */ 

         echo $studentField[1].", ".$studentField[0];
         break;

     } else if (($studentNum === $studentField[0]) &&  ($studentName === $studentField[1])) { 

        /* When both name and number is entered by user */

         echo $studentField[1].", ".$studentField[0];
         break;
      }


  }
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Using break statement within a loop provides a lot of flexibility in your code since you want to get only the first search result.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question... Neither it solves his issue.

Comment: Yes, it does. You may wanna take a closer look before you jump into conclusions, mate. :)

Comment: Yeah, after you've edited a big chunk of code?
Also what's about putting variables within single quotes?
'$studentField[0], $studentField[1]'
That's not going to output any data.
Anyway your answer got accepted, good luck with your code.

Comment: Good point about the single quotes, bud. Thanks! I've edited it now. It was a syntax error, though. It's the logic and optimization that matters a lot more. :)