# Get the index of the same value of a array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like this [this array is combination of two different arrays]:

I combine arrays and via `array_combine()` function

```
$products = array_combine($one_array_key,$second_array_values);

$products = array(
    "arn1" =>"A",
    "arn2" =>"A",
    "arn3" =>"A",
    "arn4" =>"B",
    "arn5" =>"B",
    "arn6" =>"B"
);
```

So As you can see there are two distinct values from array `A` and `B`.

I want two arrays consists of it's keys.

Or in other words: Compare values of associative array and matched values's key will be extract to the other array .

So My expected out is:

```
 $A = array("arn1","arn2","arn3");
 $B = array("arn4","arn5","arn6");
```

**My code:**

```
$products = array_combine($one_array_key,$second_array_values);
$products_distinct_values = array_count_values($product);
$products_distinct_values_keys = array_keys($products_distinct_values);

    foreach ($products as $key => $value)
    {
        // what should I need write there, to get the x numbers of array(s), containing *key* of the same *value of array*
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all array keys that has same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966490/find-all-array-keys-that-has-same-value)

Comment: @El_Vanja I want to get the x numbers of arrays, As answer by Jhon_Doe. the value of are unknow not know and are dynamic

Comment: The proposed duplicate has a dynamic solution.

Comment: I tried it but I'm trying to achieve results on different arrays

Comment: @Shani why do you _think_ you need to have individual variable declared in your global scope?  I wouldn't do this because you lose the ability to use array functions on this "collection of arrays".  Variable variables are not a good idea either.  Then what will happen in your code after you generate all of these unpredictable variable names?  How will your code know what to access?  You are going down a painful path.

Comment: @mickmackusa that my pain point I don't know how to do it properly, your answer helps me a lot, Thanks. any link, tutorial for learning PHP to solve problems like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SUPER would never use this "variable variables" technique in a professional project, but it *does* satisfy your brief.  I will urge you to find the folly in your XY Problem.

Effectively, the snippet below will synchronously iterate over the two related input arrays and create variably-named result arrays to push values into.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7NVAu))

```
$one_array_key = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'];
$second_array_values = ['arn1', 'arn2', 'arn3', 'arn4', 'arn5', 'arn6'];

foreach ($one_array_key as $index => $value) {
    $$value[] = $second_array_values[$index];
}

var_export($A);
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($B);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'arn1',
  1 => 'arn2',
  2 => 'arn3',
)
---
array (
  0 => 'arn4',
  1 => 'arn5',
  2 => 'arn6',
)
```

---

It makes much more sense to have a statically named variable containing keys and related subarrays.  This way you can call `array_keys()` on the result, if you wish, to find out which groups were found in the original input.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vcbCc))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($one_array_key as $index => $value) {
    $result[$value][] = $second_array_values[$index];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'A' => 
  array (
    0 => 'arn1',
    1 => 'arn2',
    2 => 'arn3',
  ),
  'B' => 
  array (
    0 => 'arn4',
    1 => 'arn5',
    2 => 'arn6',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Honestly, please do not use the first snippet in your project.  In a year's time, you will smack your forehead and say, "Why did I think this was a good idea!"  (I know, because I've been there.)

Comment: Perhaps if you make me a 3v4l.org link with a bit more of the context of your scenario, I may be able to help you with the design.  (after I finish my workday)

Comment: Yes, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PHP code to do that.

```
<?php
$products = array("arn1"=>"A", "arn2"=>"A", "arn3"=>"A", "arn4"=>"B", "arn5"=>"B", "arn6"=>"B");
$A = array();
$B = array();
foreach ($products as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value == "A")
    {
        array_push ($A, $key);
    }
    else if ($value == "B")
    {
        array_push ($B, $key);
    }
}
print_r ($A);
print_r ($B);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. I tried this earlier but As I update my question I need x number of array and I don't know the value of array. so if ($value == "A") is not helping as I'm dealing with random data