# Remove the [0] element from array without deleting whole array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to make a script to remove any empty elements from my array.

However an empty element is in the [0] slot so when I unset the value it deletes my whole array. At least I think that's what's happening, why isn't this working?

```
<?php

$idfile = file_get_contents("datafile.dat");
$idArray = explode("\n", $idfile);
print_r($idArray);
foreach ($idArray as $key => &$value) {
    echo "Key is: ".$key." and value is: ".$value."<br />\n";
    if ($value == ""){
        echo "Killing value of ".$value."<br />";
        unset($value[$key]);
    }
    $value = str_replace("\n", "", $value);
    $value = str_replace("\r", "", $value);
    $value = $value.".dat";
}

print_r($idArray);
?>
```

Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => test1
    [2] => test2
)
Key is: 0 and value is: <br>
Killing value of <br>
```

Comment: Try [array_shift()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the very 1st element

Comment: I'll add an extra function in their that checks if the value is "0" then use this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just removing an empty value try using `unset($idArray[$key])` instead.  If you are just trying to remove the first element overall, use `array_shift()`

Comment: I just realized how much of an idiot I am - I tried to remove $value[$key] instead of what you said. Ha, I need sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Another nice solution would be to use the [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method, which will handle the iteration and return the filtered array for you:

```
<?php

function isNotEmpty($str)
{
    return strlen($str);
}

$idfile = file_get_contents("datafile.dat");
$idArray = explode("\n", $idfile);
$idArray = array_filter($idArray, "isNotEmpty");

?>
```