# Remove null elements array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have the array `$wynik` below.

How can I delete all keys with empty [id]??

I would like to refer to specific elements.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2531291225
            [ilosc] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2531291312
            [ilosc] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] =>
            [ilosc] =>
        )
)
```

Solution:

```
foreach ($wynik as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            if (empty( $value2))
                unset($wynik[$key][$key2]);
        }
    }
    if (empty($wynik[$key]))
        unset($wynik[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

```
$filtered = array_filter($wynik, function ($v) {
  return !empty($v['id']);
});
```

Comment: How refer to specific elements in my array??

Comment: @damian Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I do update the database.
For each element in the array I need to do an if statement.
How?

if (id = id && ilosc < ilosc ){}

Comment: @damian you mean, after the array has been stripped of emtpy elements?

Comment: Can this be?:
  foreach( $wynik as $key => $value ) {
   //print_array($value);
   $ilosc = $wynik[$key]['ilosc']++;
   $id = $wynik[$key]['id']++;
   
   echo $ilosc .' - '. $id .'<br>';
  }

Comment: @damian well, just traverse the now filtered array (e.g. `$filtered` from above) like you normally would (for example using `foreach`) and do whatever needs to be done with those values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=array();
foreach($wynik as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value['id']!=NULL)
        $result=array_merge($result,array($key=>$value));
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $wynik as $key => $value ) {
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2 ) if(!empty($value2)) $Row[$key2] = $value2; 
    }
}
```