# scrub nulls from php array

Tags: php, arrays, function, null

i am having problems with a function that is supposed to return all the childern of a certian object and encode the whole thing into JSON. Currently it is working but there are a bunch of nulls in the JSON encode and i have tried `array_filter()` and a `foreach` loop to scrub them out, both didn't work.

```
findChildren($conn, $topic);

$data = array();
function findChildren($conn, $topic) {
   $rst = $conn->query("SELECT topicID, topicTitle, topicParentID, topicDeleted FROM tbl_topics WHERE topicParentID = $topic");
   while ($row = $rst->fetch_assoc()) {
      if ($row['topicDeleted'] == 0) {
         //$data[] = htmlentities($row, UTF-8);
         if($row != '') {
            $data[] = $row;   
         }

         findChildren($conn, $row['topicID']);
      }              
   }
   echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: please provide a sample json output, and a sample query result.

Comment: you're worried about NULLs in the individual columns of $row, correct?

Comment: Seems that doing this solution on $row would work out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements , although you said you tried array_filter() already.  Why didn't that work?

Comment: `if ($row != '')` doesn't make sense. `$row` is an array, not a string.

Comment: You shouldn't have `echo json_encode($data)` in the function, because it's recursive. Each time it recurses, it echoes the accumulated rows. You shouldn't do that until the outermost call returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = findChildren($conn, $topic);
echo json_encode($data);

function findChildren($conn, $topic) {
    $data = array();
    $rst  = $conn->query(
        "
            SELECT topicID, topicTitle, topicParentID, topicDeleted
            FROM tbl_topics
            WHERE topicParentID = ${topic} and topicDeleted = 0
        "
    );

    while ($row = $rst->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array_filter($row);

        if(!empty($row['topicID'])) {
            $data = array_merge(
                $data,
                findChildren($conn, $row['topicID'])
            );
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

- Changed the function to return an array, rather then echo directly, or use variable as if it was global
- Moved the 'topicDeleted' checking to the query