# Resetting position of items in array PHP

Tags: php

I have a string of 7 numbers in an array looks like 4,1,2,56,7,9,10 however sometimes these elements are empty ,,,56,7,9,10 for example. What I would like to do is reorder the array so it looks like 56,7,9,10,,,

Comment: see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements). I would go with array_filter myself.

Comment: So you don't want to *remove* the empty ones, but move them to the end?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$null_counter = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
   if($val == null) {
       $null_counter++;
       unset($array[$key]);
   }
}
for($x=1;$x<=$null_counter;$x++) {
    $array[] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unset in loop to remove null value and  shift the values Up.

```
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$val )
{
    if($yourarray[$key] == '')
    {
       unset($yourarray[$key]);
    }
}
```