# How to iterate this in a foreach construct

Tags: php, arrays

This one only covers the first record in the array -- `$form[items][0][description]`.
 How could I iterate this to be able to echo succeeding ones i.e

```
$form[items][1][description];
$form[items][2][description];
$form[items][3][description];
```

and so on and so forth?

```
$array = $form[items][0][description];

function get_line($array, $line) {
  preg_match('/' . preg_quote($line) . ': ([^\n]+)/', $array['#value'], $match);
  return $match[1];
}

$anchortext = get_line($array, 'Anchor Text');
$url = get_line($array, 'URL');

echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $anchortext . '</a>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
foreach ($form['items'] as $item) {
  echo $item['description'] . "<br>";
}
```

---

I could help you more if I saw the body of your `get_line` function, but here's the gist of it

```
foreach ($form['items'] as $item) {
  $anchor_text = get_line($item['description'], 'Anchor Text');
  $url = get_line($item['description'], 'URL');
  echo "<a href=\"{$url}\">{$anchor_text}</a>";
}
```

Comment: OK thanks for that. But how does it come with my code above? I still need to assign the values to the the $array variable. Still a noob so forgive me if I'm asking the obvious.

Comment: @xchampionx, please see my edit. I'm pretty sure I could help you quite a bit more if I saw what your `get_line` function was doing, though.

Comment: How come the solution above returns empty/non-existent elements?

Comment: Checked it against php's empty() function but still the same. Neither do the solutions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate over this array.

```
for($i=0; $i< count($form['items']); $i++)
{
    $anchortext = get_line($form['items'][$i]['description'], 'Anchor Text');
    $url = get_line($form['items'][$i]['description'], 'URL');
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $anchortext . '</a>';
}
```