# array to filter quotes only in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => '1/1/2014' 
[1] => 'abx pp' 
[2] => '' 
[3] => '' 
[4] => '<31-12-2013>' 
[5] => '' 
[6] => '' 
[7] => '555017081788' 
[8] => '' 
[9] => '' 
[10] => ''
 [11] => '1/1/2014' 
[12] => '' 
[13] => '' 
[14] => '' 
[15] => ''
 [16] => '81,072.60' )
```

I need to filter above array as below

```
Array (
 [0] => '1/1/2014' 
[1] => 'abx pp'  
[4] => '<31-12-2013>'
[7] => '555017081788' 
[11] => '1/1/2014'
[16] => '81,072.60' )
```

I tried with loops and seems to be slow
What is the best way?

Comment: I wonder why everybody has missed the easiest solution: `$arr = array_diff($arr, (array)"''");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple methods. **First**, use php function [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). `Note` that for `array_filter` function second `parameter`(**callback function**) **is not required**:

```
print_r(array_filter($yourArray);
```

**Second**, using loop:

```
foreach($yourArrayas $key => $val;) 
{ 
    if($val== '') 
    { 
        unset($yourArrayas [$key]); 
    } 
} 
print_r($linksArray);
```

Comment: '' wont be filtered using array_filter we need callback function

Comment: Why we need callback function, no, the function can filter the array without callback function

Comment: why foreach on callback function? you can simply match strings ('')

Comment: ??No foreach, no callback function

Comment: Check on simple example: $array= array(3,4,5,NULL,''); print_r(array_filter($array));

Comment: @timus2001 there is absolutely no need to callback function in this case, did you ever tried to test it ??

Comment: sorry guys , i was messed up.. thats OP to accept your answer lately .. i deleted

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [**array_filter()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter function
Please check below
[Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)  and
https://www.php.net/array_filter

but i am not sure it is fast or not.

Comment: That's really a jerk comment considering what rep he is... It takes 50 rep to comment globally. The only thing he can actually say is the answer field.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of php manual linked below :

[converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

`''` equals to false , AND this :

```
print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

will perfectly work ( tested ).

And **there is no need** to write a function to filter quotes .

Answer (score 0):

You could also expand this solution to include regexp for more powerful checks on array items.

```
array_filter($array, "removeEmptyArrayItems");

function removeEmptyArrayItems($arrayItem)
{
    if($arrayItem == '')
    {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

OR

```
foreach($array as $arrayItem)
{
    if($arrayItem == '')
    {
        unset($arrayItem);
    }
}
```

The loop on this should not be slow, to remove these you have to loop through and check each value, that is just how it works.

Comment: you dont need unset on callback function