# Ajax - Manipulate a correct array to pass to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys i am new to jQuery and I have encountered this type of problem,

I am trying to create an array from jquery to pass it on to php controller (CI).

Sample HTML

```
<input type="text" acc_id="5" class="input" />
<input type="text" acc_id="10" class="input" />
<input type="text" acc_id="15" class="input" />
<input type="text" acc_id="20" class="input" />
```

Javascript

```
$('#save').click(function(){

    var arrayVal = [];

    $('.input').each(function(key, value){

        var id = $(this).attr('acc_id');
        var inputValue = $(this).val();

        arrayVal[id] = inputValue;

    });

    $.ajax({
        url:  siteurl + '/sample_save',  
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'accounts' : arrayVal},
        success: function(data) {}
    });

});
```

Here is my response in Php

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => value 1
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => value 2
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
        [15] => value 3
        [16] => 
        [17] => 
        [18] => 
        [19] => 
        [20] => value 4
    )

)
```

Notice that the response gave me the key from 0 - 20.

But I want it like this :

```
Array
(
    [array] => Array
    (
        [5]  => value 1 
        [10] => value 2
        [15] => value 3
        [20] => value 4
    )
)
```

I can somehow make it work in Php, but I want to correct this stuff through my javascript code. Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This is clearly something that should be solved within your JS code.

jQuery has a native serialize function for forms. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for an example to use it, that may be a better approach to your problem.

Also please be aware that javaScript does not have *real* associative arrays. You are only able to use objects in a similar way as you know associative arrays from other languages (like PHP).

***Edit***

Ok, in that case your code is ok. You would just need to use an object instead of an array.

Just use:

```
var arrayVal = {};
```

Instead of:

```
var arrayVal = [];
```

Comment: I do not have a form for this fields, I am just doing a fetch for the attribute acc_id (for key ID) and its value, hehe

Comment: wooahh, this sets it all, Thanks dude! awesome.

Comment: Always glad to help. :-) [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) is some good further reading on that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could use: array_filter

```
array_filter($array);
```

There is a previous question covering the subject:
[Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

[Array filter in PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your php file:

```
$test = array('','',1,2,'',3); //your array
foreach($test as $i=>$k)
{
    if(empty($k))
    {
        unset($test[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($test);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [5] => 3 )
```

Or you can use **filter**

Code:

```
$test = array('','',1,2,'',3);
$test = array_filter($test);
print_r($test);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works in Php, but I was looking for accurate js solution, anyway, silver helped me out, but then again this is one thing to keep in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     //You can use this function and it's remove to empty array  
    <?php
             array_filter($array);
      ?>



  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
```