# Remove empty array from start of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been unable to find an elegant solution to what is a simple problem.

Basically an API call I'm making is outputting one empty array before my main set of data. What would be the fastest way of removing this from the data set?

Array structure...

```
$example = Array (
) Array (
[aaa] => Array (
[aa] => aa
[aa] => aa
[aa] => aa
[aa] => aa
)
```

Therefore the first array() needs to be removed to be:

```
$fixed = Array (
[aaa] => Array (
[aa] => aa
[aa] => aa
[aa] => aa
[aa] => aa
)
```

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Comment: not an array element, removing whole empty arrays

Comment: how are you getting your data? example of data may be helpful. `array() array(multidimensionalstartshere(), array());` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fixed = array_filter($example);
```

[Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($example[0]);
```

Wouldn't that be easy?

Or if it's associative

```
reset($example);
unset($example[key($example)];
```