# How to remove an empty element in array php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have a string which has `<br/>` in it, which is converted to an array.

```
$files = "Pretty Hurts<br/>
          Ghost/Haunted<br/>
          Drunk in Love (feat. Jay-Z)<br/>
          Blow<br/>
          No Angel<br/>
          Yoncé/Partition<br/>
          Jealous<br/>
          Rocket<br/>
          Mine (feat. Drake)
          <br/>"
 $files_to_array = explode('<br/>', $files);
```

when i print_r the array there's an empty element in the array i tried trimming the string before i add it to the array, empty elemnt still appears. how can i solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Comment: @Jeremy i i tried those solutions but they are not working, when is `print_r(array_filter($files_to_array));` this is what i get `Array ( [0] => Pretty Hurts [1] => Ghost/Haunted [2] => Drunk in Love (feat. Jay-Z) [3] => Blow [4] => No Angel [5] => YoncÃ©/Partition [6] => Jealous [7] => Rocket [8] => Mine (feat. Drake) [9] => )`

Comment: While I wasn't the downvoter, I'd say that you're probably doing it wrong if other solutions didn't work for you.

Comment: And FYI OP -- typically, you're supposed to say what you've tried in your OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter($files_to_array, "trim")`. `array_filter` without the second parameter returns all values from the original array that aren't considered equal to `false`. An empty string is equal to `false`, but a string of whitespace is not. `trim` overcomes this.
[PHP array_filter manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

we have `array_filter` function for that

simply do this

```
array_filter($files_to_array);
```

and to rebuilt the sequential keys use `array_values`

so it'll be `array_values( array_filter($files_to_array));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = "Pretty Hurts<br/>
      Ghost/Haunted<br/>
      Drunk in Love (feat. Jay-Z)<br/>
      Blow<br/>
      No Angel<br/>
      Yoncé/Partition<br/>
      Jealous<br/>
      Rocket<br/>
      Mine (feat. Drake)
      <br/>";
$files_to_array = explode('<br/>', trim($files, '<br/>'));
```