# Removing Empty Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
print_r($myArr);
```

My Current array will look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                     [P_Name] => a
                     [P_Id] => 1
                )
          [1] => Array
                (
                    [P_Name] => b
                    [P_Id] => 2
                )
          )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

I need remove empty array to be removed, it should be look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                     [P_Name] => a
                     [P_Id] => 1
                )
          [1] => Array
                (
                    [P_Name] => b
                    [P_Id] => 2
                )
          )

)
```

Comment: The output which you show us are 3 different arrays! Please show us either your full code or your real output

Comment: The two empty arrays cannot be in the same variable as the other content, otherwise it would have an index like `[1] = Array()`. I think you are printing this in a loop and sometimes it is empty?

Comment: @StephanB. yes. I m doing in that loop only. Is their anyway to remove while executing itself

Comment: @Deepak Show us your **full** code!

Comment: @Rizier123 Its very long process. I fetch data from db in two table. I need to display like a parent-child relationship.

Comment: @Deepak Just show the relevant code. The code around your print_r() statement

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3654295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_filter` for this. Try with -

```
array_filter($myArr);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/340069)

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: How are getting this array?

Comment: Same as my current array

Comment: Its worked. I give static data and used array_fliter() its worked. Error in my code from previous fetching data

Comment: :) . . i was wondering how are you getting that type of data!!