# Array explode need to remove null value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a string as follows:

```
$str = ,1,2;
```

I used explode method and make an array as follows:

```
 $idsArray = explode(",",$str);
```

I print the array as follows:

```
print_r($idsArray);
```

The result I got is as follows:

```
Array(
[0]=>
[1]=>1
[2]=>2

)
```

I need a result as

```
Array(
    [0]=>1
    [1]=>2

    )
```

How can I correct it and make the expected result?

Comment: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) might already do.

Comment: `$arr = preg_split("/,/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_filter` as

```
$idsArray = array_values(array_filter(explode(',',",1,2")));
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
print_r(array_filter($idsArray));
```

> Iterates over each value in the **array** passing them to the **callback** function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from **array** is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.

**EDIT 01**

```
$new_array = array_filter($idsArray);
```

Comment: I wanted it on array creation step. Not on printing. On creation it self it need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use array_filter

```
print_r(array_values(array_filter($idsArray)));
```

Array(
    [0]=>1
    [1]=>2
    )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$str = ",1,2";
$newarry = explode(',',trim($str,','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$tags = array_filter( explode(",", $str) ); 
var_dump($tags);
```