# PHP preg_match for empty lines

Tags: php, regex, xml

I want to have an array of strings with `<answers>` and `<names>` tags from my xml file, (it's not guaranteed for file to be valid, so I can't parse it with simplexml)

after code execution I get an array with `array[0]` equal to something empty with lenght of 5, I thought that my regexp `/^[\s\S]*$/` should remove all empty characters and lines, but on practice that `array[0]` element is stays the same as after array_filter.

how can I get this array without emty values?

```
array(8) { 
[0]=> 
string(5) " " 
[3]=> 
string(39) "<name>первый вопрос</name> " 
[4]=> 
string(68) "<answer id="1">Первый ответ на вопрос 1</answer> " 
[5]=> 
string(68) "<answer id="2">Второй ответ на вопрос 1</answer> " 
[6]=> 
string(68) "<answer id="3">Третий ответ на вопрос 1</answer> "
[9]=> 
string(51) "<name> второй вопрос</name> " 
[10]=> 
string(68) "<answer id="1">Первый ответ на вопрос 2</answer> " 
[11]=> 
string(68) "<answer id="2">Второй ответ на вопрос 2</answer> " 
}
```

I have xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<test> 
<question id="1">
<name>первый вопрос</name>
<answer id="1">Первый ответ на вопрос 1</answer>
<answer id="2">Второй ответ на вопрос 1</answer>
<answer id="3">Третий ответ на вопрос 1</answer>
</question>
<question id="2">

<name>            второй вопрос</name>
<answer id="1">Первый ответ на вопрос 2</answer>
<answer id="2">Второй ответ на вопрос 2</answer>
</question>
</test>
```

and code

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$per = preg_replace('/<question[\s\S]+?>|<\/question>|<test>|
<\/test>|<\?xml[\s\S]+?>/i', "", $xml);
$array = explode("\n", $per);
function filter($str)
{
    return !preg_match('/^[\s]*$/', $str);
}

$array = array_filter($array, "filter");
var_dump ($array);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Comment: Why not [use `preg_match_all`](https://eval.in/539189).

Comment: @ClaudioKing this doesn't working, I can have empty values and whitespaces in array with lenght more than 1

Comment: @bobblebubble this works great, but not on my server for some reason I get Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at ...

Comment: @Alexander did you use `~` as [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)? you can also escape the `\/`

Comment: @bobblebubble this works great thank you! if You write it as an answer I will accept it as one that solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple one liner.

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', file('example.xml')), 'strlen');
```

However, why do you use regular expressions to parse XML documents? I recommend you using native `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXMLElement` instead.

Example of `DOMDocument`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXMLFile('example.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$q2a1 = $xpath->evaluate('string(/question[@id="2"]/answer[@id="1"])');
```

Example of `SimpleXMLElement`:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('example.xml', 0, true);
$q2a1 = (string)$xml->xpath('/question[@id="2"]/answer[@id="1"]')->item(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace all space or white space then check is empty if not return

```
function filter($str)
    {
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);

        if($string !== ""):
           return $string;
        endif;
    }

    $array = array_filter($array, "filter");
    var_dump ($array);
```

Comment: this still get me to the array with first element [0]=>  string(5)  " "