# PHP: How to split a string in substrings that match and don't match a regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm new here and need your help. I want to match an string that is an URI - and get an array of substrings.

This is my input string:

```
/part-of-{INTERESETINGSTUFF}/an-url/{MORESTUFF}
```

I want this output array:

```
array(4) {
     [0]=>
     string(9) "/part-of-"
     [1]=>
     string(19) "{INTERESETINGSTUFF}"
     [2]=>
     string(8) "/an-url/"
     [3]=>
     string(11) "{MORESTUFF}"
}
```

I'm already able to preg_match everything with curly brackets by the pattern `\{[^}]+\}`. But how can I achieve my desired result?

Best regards!

Comment: [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) should provide you with the tools necessary to achieve your goals.

Comment: Just do a `preg_match_all` using regex: `/(.*?)({[^}]*})/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a very simple [`({[^{}]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/uUCzg4/2) regex matching `{`, zero or more symbols other than `{` and `}` with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option (that will put all the *captured* subvalues into the resulting array):

```
$str = '/part-of-{INTERESETINGSTUFF}/an-url/{MORESTUFF}';
$res = array_filter(preg_split('/({[^{}]*})/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
print_r($res);
// => Array( [0] => /part-of-  [1] => {INTERESETINGSTUFF}  [2] => /an-url/ [3] => {MORESTUFF} )
```

See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/O0ehl0)

The [`array_filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements) is used to remove all empty elements from the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option.

Comment: The point is that there must be a capturing group around the pattern to make sure the matched chunks could also be put into the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

What about this. [See on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MjW7O5/1)

```
\/.*?(?={|\/)\/?|{.*?}
```

Then store the matches in an array.

- `\/.*?` matches all character following `/`
- `(?={|\/)` stops match if next character is `{` or `/`
- `\/?` match optional `/` at the end of match
- `{.*?}` matches brackets and everything between