# Removing a nested array completely

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to solve a question related to a much bigger script. However the simple example below shows clearly the problem I am attempting to solve in the bigger script. Here is the ready to go code

```
 $a=array("Volvo",22,18);
 $b=array("BMW",15,13);
 $c=array("Saab",5,2);
 $d=array("Land Rover",17,15);

  UNSET ($a); 
  $a=array_filter($a);//remove the null values 
  $a=array_values($a);//remove the keys 

$cars = array
  (
     $a,
     $b,
     $c,
     $d,
  );


print "<pre>";
print_r($cars);
print "</pre>";
```

My question is as follows...

Unset($a) removes the content of array($a). However as can be seen from the example (print_r) the array($a) is not completely destroyed. The keys remain. That causes a big problem later on as third party validators interpret this residual array data and return a validation error. The only way to get rid of the error is to get rid of the array($a) altogether.

As you can see I have tried array_filter($a) and array_values($a). But the output is unchanged.

Anyone know how to get rid of the array($a) programmatically in this example?

Many thanks

ps Here is the output from Print_r

```
 Array
     (
      [0] => 

    [1] => Array
      (
        [0] => BMW
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 13
     )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Saab
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 2
    )

    [3] => Array
      (
        [0] => Land Rover
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 15
     )

 )
```

Comment: _"as can be seen from the example (print_r)"_... I don't see any result from the `print_r()` in your question.

Comment: Turn on Error Reporting and see what you get

Comment: Notice: `Undefined variable: a in tst.php on line 12`

Comment: In PHP7 & 5.6 & 5.5 `$a` is destroyed and the `print_r()` shows array[0] as NULL

Comment: The output of what you posted here is Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Land Rover
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 15
        )

). I'm not sure what it is that you think isn't happening

Comment: I have updated the question to include the output. I am trying to get rid of the  [0] => as this is seen as a null (none) value by the third party validator

Comment: `Unset($a) removes the content of array($a).` no, it unset $a. However,the keys? There are no array keys in your example. And `have tried array_filter(` do you really now what these function are doing?

Comment: Riggs---you are right. My problem is I need to get rid of the  [0] =>. As you say it is a null value. I need  the array to be completely destroyed--deleted inits entirety

Comment: check [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Comment: `get rid of` then use array_filter on `$cars` and array_values after that to refresh the index

Comment: Joum--i am attempting to show you what I have tried and yes I have taken the trouble to read up on these functions.  Please respect I am doing my best to explain that

Comment: WEBjuju--this seems to be a very similar problem. Thank you for your help in pointing that out. I will try a few new things based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this solution working over at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/9ZSaC).

```
$cars = [
    [ 'Volvo', 22, 28 ],     // index 0
    [ 'BMW', 15, 13 ],       // index 1
    [ 'Add Cars', X, Y ]     // index i
];

unset($cars[0]);  // unset Volvo
unset($cars[1]);  // unset BMW
unset($cars[$i]); // unset index
```

If your cars are hard coded then this words fine, however, if you need to create checks against the cars then I'd suggest creating associative arrays on the cars like so:

```
$cars = [ 'all' =>
            [
                'brand' => 'Volvo',
                'X'     => 22,
                'Y'     => 28
            ],
            [
                'brand' => 'BMW',
                'X'     => 15,
                'Y'     => 13
            ]
        ];

foreach($cars['all'] as $car){
    if($car['brand'] == 'Volvo') {
        unset($car['brand']); // unset Volvo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you KDOT. You were obviously writing this when i was testing the script i was referred to. I think your solution is definitely much more complete with the foreach method. I will  incorporate this into the final solution. Thank you again

Comment: I just entered your second code snippet and print_r yielded the following output  Array
(
    [all] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Volvo
            [X] => 22
            [Y] => 28
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => BMW
            [X] => 15
            [Y] => 13
        )

)

Comment: Is this what you were expecting KDOT (not sure that Volvo was unset)?

Comment: `unset($cars['all']['brand']);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to WEjuju i have a solution which is dead simple. Good job someone understands array_filter. It did the job as follows:

```
                $a=array("Volvo",22,18);
                $b=array("BMW",15,13);
                $c=array("Saab",5,2);
                $d=array("Land Rover",17,15);
                UNSET ($a);
                $cars = array
                  (
                        $a,
                        $b,
                        $c,
                        $d,
                  );

                print "<pre>";
                print_r($cars);
                print_r(array_filter($cars));//note the use of the filter after unset
                print "</pre>";

                ?>
```

The output is now....

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
      (
        [0] => BMW
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 13
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Saab
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 2
    )

 [3] => Array
      (
         [0] => Land Rover
         [1] => 17
         [2] => 15
       )

 )
```

No pesky [0]=> interfereing with validation.