# Removing null or blank values of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, I just print it as-
print_r($data);
It shows output as-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => Featured Image
            [2] => Catagories
            [3] => Tags
            [4] => Content
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 1
            [1] => img1.jpg
            [2] => cat 1
            [3] => tag 1
            [4] => post 1 content
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 2
            [1] => img2.jpg
            [2] => cat2
            [3] => tag 2
            [4] => post 2 content
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => title 3
            [1] => img3.jpg
            [2] => cat3
            [3] => tag3
            [4] => post 3 content
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )

)
```

I just want to remove blank or null values from array.
I tried array_dif() and array_filter() but still I couldn't remove null values.
How is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: try to read al larray and generate a new array without null values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Comment: Loop over the main array and filter the array value using the array_filter;

Comment: So you want to remove elements 4, 5, 6 from main array right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array, look for empty variables and use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove them.

---

This code will loop through and check if the length of the first value in each array is at least one character long and unset it if its not.

```
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($value[0][0]))
        unset($data[$key]);
}
```

---

This code will loop through the array in a similar way, except to check every value of every array to determine if its parrent array should be kept or left to be unset.

```
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $value) {
        if(isset($value[0]))
            continue 2;
    }
    unset($data[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use array_filter with a function that also runs array_filters against the subarrays and returns false if the filtered subarrays become empty.

```
<?php

$array = Array(
    Array(1, 2, 3),
    Array(null, null, null),
    Array(false, false, false),
    Array(3, 2, 1)
);

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($elem) {
    return count(array_filter($elem));
});

print_r($filtered);

?>
```