# How to remove 'null' values in laravel controller while retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filtering

The results in $data variable. I want to remove null values at output.

The following code:

```
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
```

I am copying `$data` to `$data1` later to merge the two variables using below code:

```
$data1 = $data;
$unique= array_merge($data1,$data);
$final =array_values(array_map("unserialize",array_unique(array_map("serialize", $unique))));
```

Comment: `$data ` being what exactly? If it's a collection then you can apply filters:`$data->filter(function ($element, $key) {
 return $element!==null;
});`

Comment: actually, i am fetching data from database to $data array.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink what you are doing: Encoding and then decoding, serializing and then unserializing, merging it with itself... Surely there is an easier way to get the results you need.

Comment: This looks like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I suggest, instead of this question, ask a question about the problem you were trying to solve and came up with this solution. As it stands, this code is doing a lot of things that are a bit sub-optimal.

Comment: This question does not contain a [mcve] and is Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array_filter** to remove the null value fro the array

Do like this

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
$data =array_filter($data);
```

**Modification**
As you are dealing with Multi dimensional array (as you said in comment),to remove the array which have null data you need to use **array_map** , **array_filter** and **in_array**.

Do like this

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
$data =array_map('array_filter',$data);
$data=array_map(function ($data){
            if(!in_array(null,$data))
                return $data;
        },$data);
$data=array_filter($data);
```

It will give output as
[image]

It will work for you.

Comment: in $data array i have some data and $data1 have some data so i merged two arrays and return to array_map ().

Comment: okay you can use `array_filter() ` when you need to remove your null value from your data array.

Comment: still same issue using array_filter().

Comment: Can you please show your data what you have now and what you want to be.

Comment: The following code have for the material null, so i remove for that null and give only valued data                                                                                                                                                        .[0]=> array(3) { ["iot"]=> int(1172141637653120) ["datetime"]=> string(19) "2017-05-11 11:32:39" ["material"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(3) { ["iot"]=> int(8567763953469695) ["datetime"]=> string(19) "2017-05-11 11:32:39" ["material"]=> string(13) "2134803942910" }

Comment: yes i tried, but i need where ever the material code is NULL, that particular index should be removed and give output.

Comment: like that only its working now it just removing the ** material code is NULL** just check the o/p `array[0]`

Comment: yes but i need remove whole index like its iot, date, material_code, where ever the material_code is NULL.so for above two array responses i need only one array response.

Comment: @Prashanthvadla now i got your problem just try this modified ans.

Comment: No, its not coming can you check it once!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148396/discussion-between-bibhudatta-sahoo-and-prashanth-vadla).

Comment: @Prashanthvadla if your issue is solved then close your question by accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**array_filter** will work perfectly if you're only working with arrays containing strings. Be careful otherwise as **array_filter** will also remove 0, '', and `false`.

See this answer: [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 0):

If both `$data` adn `$data1` are database results I can assume they are collections.

Then you can make 1 collection by applying [union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-union): `$data->union($data1);`

After which you can [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) the result set:

`$data->filter(function ($element, $key) { 
     return $element!==null; 
});`