# PHP: Ignore og remove empty line at the end of list

Tags: php

I have PHP script that fetches a list of IP-adresses from an URL, prepends and appends some text and linebreaks to it.
This works well, except the source has an empty line at the end, and that makes a line without IP-adress.
I need the script to ignore or delete that line, so that it is not generated.

```
<?php
$ipPage = file_get_contents('https://my.pingdom.com/probes/ipv4');
$ipList = explode("\n", $ipPage);
echo "/ip firewall address-list\n";
echo "remove [/ip firewall address-list find list=Pingdom]\n";
foreach($ipList as $ip) {
    echo "add address=" . $ip . " list=Pingdom\n";
  }
?>
```

You can see the result and the empty last line at https://novaram.dk/mikrotik.php

Comment: maybe try using `array_filter` just after exploding? Like: `$ipList = array_filter(explode("\n", $ipPage))`. It will remove every item with a value that equals false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Comment: Also you could just check if the `$ip` var is truthy, like `foreach ($ipList as $ip) { if ($ip) { echo "...."; } }`, or use trim `$ipPage = trim($ipPage);`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `implode()` to join them.

```
<?php
$ipPage = file_get_contents('https://my.pingdom.com/probes/ipv4');
$ipList = explode("\n", $ipPage);
echo "/ip firewall address-list\n";
echo "remove [/ip firewall address-list find list=Pingdom]\n";
foreach($ipList as $ip) {
    $ips[] = "add address={$ip} list=Pingdom";
}

echo implode("\n", $ips);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<?php
$ipPage = file_get_contents('https://my.pingdom.com/probes/ipv4');
$ipList = preg_split ( "\n", $ipPage , -1 ,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
echo "/ip firewall address-list\n";
echo "remove [/ip firewall address-list find list=Pingdom]\n";
foreach($ipList as $ip) {
    echo "add address=" . $ip . " list=Pingdom\n";
  }
?>
```

or this should work

```
<?php
$ipPage = file_get_contents('https://my.pingdom.com/probes/ipv4');
$ipList = explode("\n", $ipPage);
echo "/ip firewall address-list\n";
echo "remove [/ip firewall address-list find list=Pingdom]\n";
foreach($ipList as $ip) {
    if(strlen(trim($ip)) != 0 )
        echo "add address=" . $ip . " list=Pingdom\n";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers, I got the following to work:

```
<?php
$ipPage = file_get_contents('https://my.pingdom.com/probes/ipv4');
$ipPage = str_replace("'","",$ipPage);
$ipList = explode("\n", $ipPage);
echo "/ip firewall address-list\n";
echo "remove [/ip firewall address-list find list=Pingdom]\n";
foreach($ipList as $ip) {
    if(strlen($ip) > 0) {
        echo "add address=" . $ip . " list=Pingdom\n";
    }
}
?>
```

...but what I have a similar script, but the source sends me a list where I need to ignore the first line?