# how to remove empty array value with key in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an array similar to the following one.

```
{"form_data":["1","2","4","5","","6"],"final_data":["1","2","4","5","","6"]}
```

If form data values are `null`, I want to replace that key's value with the value of the next key.
Like above, after value 5, I have null values.  It needs to be like this:

```
"final_data":["1","2","4","5","fill this with 6","remove this"]
"final_data":["1","2","4","5","6"] like this
```

I tried `array_filter()`, but it didn't help.

Comment: `array_flter` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 2):

If the response is in json format then ...

```
$json = '{"form_data":["1","2","4","5","","6"],"final_data":["1","2","4","5","","6"]}';
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($array as $index => $a) {
  $array[$index] = array_filter($a);
}

print_r($array);
```

https://eval.in/866379

**Update**:

```
foreach($array as $index => $a) {
  $array[$index] = array_value(array_filter($a));
}
```

https://eval.in/866522

Comment: @MassoodUrRehman thanks 
 but in your example possible to index value can be 4 not 5

Comment: Yes you can use array_value() on array_filter() response that will re-indexed the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

try following code,

```html
foreach($myarray as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_null($value) || $value == '')
        unset($myarray[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `array_filter()` with `array_map()` and `array_values()`

```
<?php
    $array = array("form_data" => array("1","2","4","5","","6"), "final_data" => array("1","2","4","5","","6"));
    function filterMe($paraArr){
        return array_values(array_filter($paraArr));
    }
    $array = array_map("filterMe",$array);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
```

check the output here https://eval.in/866401