# Remove empty values from PHP array but keep 0

Tags: php

I have an array

```
array (size=7)
0 => string '2' 
1 => string '' 
2 => string '' 
3 => string '0' 
4 => string '' 
5 => string '' 
6 => string '2.5'
```

I used:-

`array_filter()`

to remove the null values and it returns

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [6] => 2 )
```

`array_filter()` removes null value and also '0' value.

Any builtin function is available in PHP to remove NULL values only.

Comment: What is the code, which you used with `array_filter()`?

Comment: `<?php

$entry = array(
             0 => '2',
             1 => '',
             2 => '',
             3 => '0',
             4 => '',
             5 => '',
             6 => '2'
             
          );

print_r(array_filter($entry));
?>` This is my code I used array_filter() and it removes 0 value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

see here

Comment: `array_filter($array,'strlen')` Code is worked

Comment: @Athi - that would also remove empty strings as well, which is not the same as `NULL`.  You can use a closure as your callback to control what gets filtered.

Comment: @Athi  `NULL != ''`, so i think  you want to remove null as well as empty strings too from your array.Isn't it?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh your coding is working fine. I want to remove empty value

Comment: *"I used `array_filter()` to remove the null values"* -- your input array does not contain `NULL` values. It contain empty strings (`''`) and they are not the same as `NULL`. [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) means the absence of any value, an empty string is a string of length `0`. They are completely different concepts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assumption:  I think you want to remove `NULL` as well as empty-strings/values `''` from your array. (What i understand from your desired output)

You have to use `array_filter()` with `strlen()`

```
array_filter($array,'strlen');
```

Output:-

https://eval.in/926585

https://eval.in/926595

https://eval.in/926602

***Refrence:-***

[PHP: array_filter - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

[PHP: strlen - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: This will also filter out `false`, in addition to `null` and `''`

Answer (score 16):

Both `0` and `''` are considered falsey in php, and so would be removed by array filter without a specific callback.  The suggestion above to use `'strlen'` is also wrong as it also remove an empty string which is not the same as `NULL`.  To remove only `NULL` values as you asked, you can use a closure as the callback for `array_filter()` like this:

```
array_filter($array, function($v) { return !is_null($v); });
```

Comment: Your coding is not working. It returns all values in the array.

Comment: @Athi - that's because the array in your question contains no `NULL` values.

Comment: Not your problem :) Even I thought OP said *Any builtin function is available in PHP to remove NULL values only.* **Until an edit**

Comment: Okay . I understand

Answer (score 4):

You can remove empty value and then re-index the array elements by using array_values() and array_filter() function together as such:

```
$arr = array("PHP", "HTML", "CSS", "", "JavaScript", null, 0);
print_r(array_values(array_filter($arr)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PHP
    [1] => HTML
    [2] => CSS
    [3] => JavaScript
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In case your array could contain line feeds and you want to filter them out as well, you may want to trim values first:

```
$arrayItems = ["\r", "\n", "\r\n", "", " ", "0", "a"];
$newArray = array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $arrayItems), 'strlen'));
// Output(newArray): ["0", "a"]

//Another great snippet to remove empty items from array
$newArray = array_filter($arrayItems , function ($item) {
    return !preg_match('/^\\s*$/', $item);
    // filter empty lines
});
// Output(newArray): ["0", "a"]
```

If you face any issue with implementing the code just comment here below.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFilter($var){
  return ($var !== NULL && $var !== FALSE && $var !== '');
}

$res = array_filter($yourArray, 'myFilter');
```

If you just need the numeric values you can use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) as your callback

**Demo**

```
$res = array_filter($values, 'is_numeric');
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7.4:

```php
$withoutNulls = array_filter($withNulls, static fn($e) => $e !== null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove null values from array

```
$array = array("apple", "", 2, null, -5, "orange", 10, false, "");

var_dump($array);

echo "<br>";



// Filtering the array

$result = array_filter($array);                 

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation would help in understanding this solution and how this may be applied to similar problems.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: array_filter without callback will remove any value that can be casted to false by PHP such as '',0, '0', false, null, []. Your claim "Remove null values from array" is bad documentation so I'll add a negative score until proper documentation is provided.