# How to get the first key from array which is not empty among multiple keys

Tags: php

I have varieties of keys assume 10 in array and i care about only 3 keys

```
non empty keyA or non empty keyB or non empty keyC
```

the keys will always be present, but they may be empty, i just care about any of the above 3 keys which is not empty.

if any one of the 3 keys exists(first no matter which one) and is not empty , break the loop and get the key.

```
//example for KeyA 
if (array_key_exists("keya", $array) && !empty($array['keya'])) {
return keya;
break;
}
```

is there a way to do it in elegant/advised/optimized way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is quite easy with some of the advanced array handling, and particularly `array_filter` - even without a custom callback.

```
<?php
$x = [ 'a' => '', 'b' => '', 'c' => 'x' ];
var_dump(array_filter($x));
```

As described on [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), if no callback function is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see converting to [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.  That includes the boolean `FALSE`, 0 (int and float), the empty string, and the string "0", arrays with zero elements and NULL.

Results:

```
array(1) {
  ["c"]=>
  string(1) "x"
}
```

When you have all the non-empty values, getting the first one, is also easy, with `current()`.

Comment: I have edited the question to , mention that there might be more than three keys

Comment: Is there not a built-in function that considers 0 to be set/non-empty but an empty string to be empty? It looks like `empty` isn't kind to 0, while `isset` treats an empty string as non-empty.