# PHP Array - delete empty element, only get populated string

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in PHP, which I'm pulling from a JSON file. I've tried carrying out a foreach to fetch only the supplier names, but to no avail.

Ideally, I'd like to just return CB DESIGN and DESIGN COMPANY but any time I've tried this, it either returns the following:

```
array(4322)
    [0]=> array(1) {["supplier"]=> array(0) { }}
    [1]=> array(1) {["supplier"]=> array(0) { }}
    [2]=> array(1) {["supplier"]=> array(0) { }}
    [3]=> array(1) {["supplier"]=> array(1) {[0]=> string(29) " CB DESIGN "}}
    [4]=> array(1) {["supplier"]=> array(1) {[0]=> string(19) " DESIGN COMPANY "}}
```

I only want to return the company names, is there any way to strip out the empty elements, I've tried using array_filter but it keeps returning the same, as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Comment: did you try to use `json_decode()` function

Comment: Yes, it's already been through the json_decode, and I've tried the array_filter but it doesn't seem to strip out the blank elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misused the array_filter.

This code returns only elements with non-empty `supplier`

**Input:**

```
$arr = [
    ["supplier" => []],
    ["supplier" => []],
    ["supplier" => []],
    ["supplier" => [" CB DESIGN "]],
    ["supplier" => [" DESIGN COMPANY "]],
];

$arrFiltered = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    return !empty($item["supplier"]);
});
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["supplier"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) " CB DESIGN "
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["supplier"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) " DESIGN COMPANY "
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but when I try to put in the code to output just the supplier names, nothing is returned.

    foreach ($arrFiltered as &$value) {
    echo $value['supplier'];
}

Comment: `foreach($arrFiltered as $value){
 echo $value['supplier'][0];
} ` try this foreach @CalBrown

Comment: Sorry, figured out what I was doing wrong! Got it sorted it now!

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys! :D