# Get the lowest variable in an array

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, min

I need to get the lowest among the values of 5 variables.

I want that if a variable is **not set or it is empty**, the script must exclude this variable from the results.

```
$var1='17';
$var2='19';
$var3='20';
$var4='1';
$var5='';

$arr = compact('var1','var2','var3','var4','var5');  // Stores values in array $arr

$highval = max($arr);
$lowval  = min($arr);
$stores=count(array_filter($arr));

echo 'Item is available in '.$stores.' vars and is between '.$lowval.' and '.$highval.'';
```

For example assigning `$var4=''`, the lowest value would be `$var1` and not `$var4`. There can also be multiple variables as not set or empty.

How would you edit the script above to accomplish it?

Comment: Why not just define an array instead of making your code bloated?

Comment: If your variable names end in numbers, you're using the wrong variables.

Comment: Use `array_filter` __before__ finding min/max.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 3):

$arr have String values in the array so need to convert in number then your problem will solve.

Add line : `$arr = array_map('intval', $arr);` line for convert in number.

**Try this:**

```
$var1='17';
$var2='19';
$var3='20';
$var4='1';
$var5='';

$arr = compact('var1','var2','var3','var4','var5');  // Stores values in array $arr
$arr = array_map('intval', $arr);
$arr1 = array_filter($arr, function($a) { return ($a !== 0); }); // Remove if Array value have 0

$highval = max($arr1);
$lowval  = min($arr1);
$stores=count($arr);

echo 'Item is available in '.$stores.' vars and is between '.$lowval.' and '.$highval.'';
```

**Ourput :**

```
Item is available in 4 vars and is between 1 and 20
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `array_filter` to show count, then you can use it before min/max. The code should like:

```
<?php    
    $var1 = '17';
    $var2 = '19';
    $var3 = '20';
    $var4 = '1';
    $var5 = '';

    $arr = compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5');  // Stores values in array $arr
    $filtered = array_filter($arr);
    $highval = max($filtered);
    $lowval = min($filtered);
    $stores = count($filtered);

    echo 'Item is available in ' . $stores . ' vars and is between ' . $lowval . ' and ' . $highval . '';
```

**UPDATE**

It would be better if you take array of numbers and write it like:

```
$arr = ['17', '19', '20', '1', ''];
$filtered = array_filter($arr);
$highval = max($filtered);
$lowval = min($filtered);
$stores = count($filtered);

echo 'Item is available in ' . $stores . ' vars and is between ' . $lowval . ' and ' . $highval . '';
```