# how to get empty index foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

Here i am having one array, using this array i have to get the `index` like which having null or empty values,i goggled it but i am not getting my expected answer,kindly  see below i have posted my expected answer.

> print_r($val);

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 4 A
    [tripID] => 
    [startFrom] => 1
    [limit] => 20
    [cabID] => 
)
```

> Expected answer

1. tripID
2. cabID

Comment: Do you select data from database?Give us the code and query and loops. I'm afraid I can't help you with just a printed array because the printed array is just the result of problem not the problem itself.

Comment: I'm not sure the sample array is valid.  You are missing the comma at the end of each line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

Answer (score 2):

This should help -

```
$a = array
(
    'ID' => '4 A',
    'tripID' => '',
    'startFrom' => 1,
    'limit' => 20,
    'cabID' => '',
);
// Filter array if value is  blank or null but not 0
$check = array_filter($a, function($v) {
  return $v == '' || $v == null;
});
// Extract the keys
print_r(array_keys($check));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => tripID
    [1] => cabID
)
```

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

This function should put you in the right direction [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Seems like a homeworkey question, mind.