# How to remove an index from array if it's giving null value

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a donor list on database which all have some point data. User can select few donors to show their point table on frontend by their id. A function is for getting user point info as array from database. I have generated tab for each donor. And the first tab will be active by default.

```
<?php
    foreach ($userGivenDonorID as $donor){
        $data = Libary::get_point($donor);

        if($donor=== reset($userGivenDonorID )){
            echo '<li class="tablink active">'.$donor['name'].'</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li class="tablink">'.$donor['name'].'</li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Now the problem is I want to skip a donor id if it's not having any point data on database thus giving an empty array for `Libary::get_point($donor)`. Cause if for any reason I don't have any data for the first user given id I don't get the first tab active by default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Comment: I assume $data is the array?

you can always do a check if $data array is empty with the empty() function

Comment: This is not a accurate duplicate, I think. I am not asking about the empty `$donor`. I am asking about the `$data` get by using it on a function. @Marcin Orlowski

Answer (score 1):

Just for common practice, you can write:

```
if($donor=== reset($userGivenDonorID )){
    echo '<li class="tablink active">'.$donor['name'].'</li>';
} else {
    echo '<li class="tablink">'.$donor['name'].'</li>';
}
```

like:

```
$active = $donor === reset($userGivenDonorID) ? 'active' : '';
echo '<li class="tablink '.$active.'">'.$donor['name'].'</li>';
```

Comment: Thanks for mention this shorthand practice. Although, This was not my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you can check the value of `$data` and use `continue`

```
$data = Libary::get_point($donor);
```

Then use for example:

```
if (null === $data) continue;
```

Or

```
if (empty($data)) continue;
```