# How to delete the next line that has no data or is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a problem with the deleting of next line empty data using laravel. Where did I go wrong?

I tried using this code explode, str_replace and array_map but still i don't get want i want.

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "\n", $tempData[0]);
$your_arrays = array_map("trim", explode("\n", $string));

print_r ($your_arrays);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => Sample Text1
    [3] => 
    [4] => Sample text 2
    [5] => Sample Text 3
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => Sample Text 4
    [9] => Sample Text 5
    [10] => Sample Text 6
    [11] => Sample Text 7
    [12] => Sample Text 8
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
)
```

I'm expecting the result with this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Sample Text1
    [2] => Sample text 2
    [3] => Sample Text 3
    [4] => Sample Text 4
    [5] => Sample Text 5
    [6] => Sample Text 6
    [7] => Sample Text 7
    [8] => Sample Text 8
)
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to remove all the empty entries in an array.

Answer (score 3):

use `array_filter` to remove all

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

```
    $var = array(
       0 => 'foo',
       1 => false,
       2 => -1,
       3 => null,
       4 => ''
   );

    print_r(array_filter($var));
```

Comment: Hello! Better to link the english version of the manual. Careful that, according to [php boolean conversion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) also a string equal to '0' is considered false and removed by `array_filter()` without a callback, may not be what the OP wants. May be better to define a proper callback.

Comment: All entries of array equal to FALSE [bool conversion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) will be removed. So if you need to preserve elements that are i.e. exact string '0', you will need a custom callback

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), which conveniently handles all this for you:

print_r(array_filter($Your_Array));