# PHP Output of NULL/Spaces

Tags: php, mysql, null, trim

I'm trying to output from mysql using php. The SQL query that I'm outputting contains several joins and some of the values are NULL. When I echo the output I get empty spaces for the NULL values. How do I get rid of the empty space? I have line breaks between each value that I want to output, but the NULL values are just placing an empty space. So my output looks a bit like this.

***What it looks like***

Dave Smith
Subject 1

Subject 3

John Smith
Subject 1
Subject 2

Subject 4

***What I'd like it to look like***

Dave Smith
Subject 1
Subject 3

John Smith
Subject 1
Subject 2
Subject 4

I have tried a few of the php trim functions, but none seem to work. The relevant code is below.

```
$resultSet = $db->query ("...my query");  

echo $resultSet -> num_rows;

While($rows = $resultSet ->fetch_assoc())

{
  $FirstName = ($rows['First_Name']);
  $Surname =   ($rows['Surname']);
  $subject1 = ($rows['subject1']);
  $subject2 = ($rows['subject2']);
  $subject3 = ($rows['subject3']);
  $subject4 = ($rows['subject4']);

  $output .= "<p> $FirstName $Surname <br/> Chosen Subjects <br/> $subject1 <br/> $subject2 <br/> 
  $subject3 <br/>  $subject4 </p>";
 }
```

Comment: Btw what's the purpose of brackets here `($rows['subject4'])`?

Comment: No purpose. I’d forgotten to remove them after attempting various trim functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I echo the output I get empty spaces for the NULL values
>
> ```
> $subject1 = ($rows['subject1']);
> $subject2 = ($rows['subject2']);
> $subject3 = ($rows['subject3']);
> $subject4 = ($rows['subject4']);
>
>   $output .= "<p> $FirstName $Surname <br/> Chosen Subjects <br/> $subject1 <br/> 
>   $subject2 <br/>  $subject3 <br/>  $subject4 </p>";
> ```

The reason for your empty space is that you are putting in `<br/>` regardless as to if any PHP value is present.

## Suggested Alternative:

- Put the values into an array.
- Clean any `falsey` / `null` values from the array
- [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array into the final string.

a) Put the values into an array:

```
$subject[1] = $rows['subject1'];
$subject[2] = $rows['subject2'];
$subject[3] = $rows['subject3'];
$subject[4] = $rows['subject4'];
```

b) Clean out the `null` values **[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38081606/3536236)**

```
$subjectOutput = array_filter($subject, 'strlen');
```

*Note: If you don't care about other `falsey` values such as 0 then you can simply do an even more basic [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) call such as `= array_filter($subject);`.*

c) [Implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array.

```
$subjectString = implode($subjectOutput, '<br/>');
```

## Example:

```
$subject[1] = "horses";
$subject[2] = 12;
$subject[3] = 0;
$subject[4] = null;
$subject[5] = "cats";

$subjectOutput = array_filter($subject, 'strlen');

//$subject[1] = "horses";
//$subject[2] = 12;
//$subject[3] = 0;
//$subject[5] = "cats";

/***
 * simply print the sting and voila!
 ***/
$subjectString = implode($subjectOutput, '<br/>');

// $subjectString = "horses<br/>12<br/>0<br/>cats";

 $output .= "<p> $FirstName $Surname <br/> Chosen Subjects <br/> ".$subjectString." </p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following code:

```
$output = "<p>{$FirstName} {$Surname}<br/>Chosen Subjects:<br/>";
$output .= (!empty($subject1)) ? "{$subject1}<br/>" : "";
$output .= (!empty($subject2)) ? "{$subject2}<br/>" : "";
$output .= (!empty($subject3)) ? "{$subject3}<br/>" : "";
$output .= (!empty($subject4)) ? "{$subject4}<br/>" : "";
$output .= "</p>";
```

Comment: For what it's worth, both `empty(0)` and `empty('0')` return `true`.

Comment: There's a lot of Repetition going on there. [**Dont' Repeat Yourself.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @Martin based on the code example in the question it was clearly needed to keep things simple and for that the simple repeating code