# I don't want to show null value in array using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to show value in array but all value is showing in array but i need to show all those record which is not null how can i remove  null in array Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.

**Note :** only i want to get value which already exist into database not null values
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,null,null,null,null]

**COntroller**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $project = Project::with('projectBillingInfo')->where('is_amc', 1)->get();


        foreach ($project as  $key => $value) {
            $count = 0;

            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->jan != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->feb != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->mar != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->apr != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->may != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->june != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->july != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->aug != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->sep != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->oct != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->nov != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            if ($value->projectBillingInfo->dec != null) {

                $count = $count += 1;
            }
            
            
            $months = [
                $value->projectBillingInfo->jan,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->feb,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->mar,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->apr,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->may,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->june,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->july,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->aug,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->sep,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->oct,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->nov,
                $value->projectBillingInfo->dec,
            ];
            return $months;

            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,null,null,null,null]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**use** `array_filter()`

**example**:

```
$result = array_filter($array);
```

array_filter() remove empty array elements from array.

Answer (score 0):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654309/10573560):

```
$month=array_filter($month);
```

if you did not provide a  callback for array_filter, all entries of array equal to FALSE or Null will be removed