# How to remove null values with PHP?

Tags: php, json, code-cleanup

I'm new dealing with JSONs and PHP and I'm having problems to clean out this type of array. here what I thought could work but I don't understand yet how it didn't works

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    if ($items[$i][] === null) {
        unset($items[$i]['']);
    }
}
```

```
[
    { 
        "ticketNumber": Ha&51,
        "qty": 0, 
        "title": "Wheat", 
        "price": 44.2,
        "purchaseDate": null,
        "date": null
    },
    { 
        "ticketNumber": H88i51,
        "qty": 2, 
        "title": "Prince",
        "price": 12.99,
        "purchaseDate": null,
        "date": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
<?php

$s = <<<eof
[{"ticketNumber": "Ha&51","qty": 0,"title": "Wheat", "price":
44.2,"purchaseDate": null,"date": null},{        "ticketNumber": "H88i51","qty":
2, "title": "Prince", "price": 12.99,"purchaseDate": null,"date": null}]
eof;

$m_json = json_decode($s, true);
$f = fn ($v): bool => $v !== null;

foreach ($m_json as $m_tick) {
   $a[] = array_filter($m_tick, $f);
}

var_export($a);
```

Personally I don't like this, as you are passing values of different types to the filter function. With a strongly typed language, this wouldn't be allowed. But the alternative would be to enumerate the "good" properties, so it seemed like a good compromise in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops, just use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php

$array = array(1 => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  2 => null);
print_r($array);

$arrayFiltered = array_filter($array);
print_r($arrayFiltered);
```

Here's a short [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc05701aa3f867a057b3a457287d3f5b53bd0185)