# Append comma only if field is not empty

Tags: php

So I have the following snippet which I'm using to build a URL structure:

```
$map_url = 'https://google.com/maps/search/'.get_field('brand', $office).
' '.get_field('location', $office).
' '.get_field('address_line_1', $office).
', '.get_field('address_line_2', $office).
', '.get_field('city', $office).
', '.get_field('state', $office).
', '.get_field('zip_code', $office).
', '.get_field('country', $office);
```

When there are fields missing, I get the following outputs:

> Edificio World Trade Center, Torre B, Avenida Francisco de Orellana,
> Guayaquil, , , Ecuador

Is there anyway to avoid appending the commas if a field is empty? Or is there a better way to structure my URL using all the ACF fields?

Comment: You could place all the values in an array, filter out the empty ones and implode.

Comment: Check if function result is empty before echoing it.

Comment: @El_Vanja, what's the best approach to take on that?

Comment: Can you post a desired URL? Not everyone knows how the Google Maps search URL looks like.

Comment: Spaces inside a url? Don't forget to [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array with [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) so we don't need to check each value manually.

We can use [`array_filter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements) to remove any 'invalid' (empty) values.

Take a look at this example

```php
<?php

// Empty array
$res = [];

// Push some values
$res[] = 'location';
$res[] = 'Guayaquil';
$res[] = '';            // Empty string to 'fake' invalid get_field result

// Remove any empty values
$res = array_filter($res);

// Implode the array with ', '
$res = implode(', ', $res);

// Show result
echo $res; 

// location, Guayaquil
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Bi8IwFITP7a@Yw0IUCv6AKnsS2dviHkWWYJ8mmDQxeVH667sxUuleZ@Z7b8YrP47rT698Xa9W2FrPA2QIcqg/AkVscDi2xfpOUSE6S7hLkygW/3DMCWHcSbJ2vWhn4i7JQd6SNv9U0aKqqvenyEH3F7CDOMsrCeg@X9cdLsS/Z02mQ0aT4VJhT9bdCbIfQAWfNcnHS@1MGaaweGrLV/Mv611HYEWvCB6aFUQDMZHaepMji6fWYIb@KPeYGtBJueK1KN60usF76jj@AQ)