# Laravel query where In with empty array clasue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have array like this

```
$ans = [1,2,3];
$ans2 = [5, 4]
$ans3 = [6,7];
```

Syntax 1 :

```
 $query->whereIn($field , $ans);
 $query->whereIn($field1 , $ans2);
 $query->whereIn($field2 , $ans3); //problem is here when array 
//has null value it doesnt work as expected
```

so query is something like

```
select * from table 
where field in (1,2,3) 
and field1 in (5,4) 
and field2 in (6,7)
```

result is correct because it is doing and for all field && field1 && field2

but when input has null it didn't work as expected

```
$ans = [1,2,3];
$ans2 = [5, 4]
$ans3 = [6,null];
```

now my query is

first solution

```
 $query->whereIn($field , $ans);
 $query->whereIn($field1 , $ans2);
 $query->whereIn($field2 , $ans3); //problem is here when array has null value
```

it doesnt work as expected

this dont work as we have null in  feild3 so result is []

```
 $query->whereIn($field , $ans);
 $query->whereIn($field1 , $ans2);
 $searchArray = collect($field2)->filter()->all();//filter array having null values
 $query->whereIn($field2, $searchArray)
 $query->where($field2 , null);
```

so query becomes something like this

```
select * from table 
    where field in (1,2,3) 
    and field1 in (5,4) 
    and field2 in (6)
    and field2 is null //wrong as field should have or in null case because i want to get field2 having 6 or null
```

that leads me to this

```
     $query->whereIn($field , $ans);
     $query->whereIn($field1 , $ans2);
     $searchArray = collect($field2)->filter()->all();//filter array having null values
     $query->whereIn($field2, $searchArray)
     ->orWhereNull($field2);
```

result is field2 having 6 and also null but not it dont take care of other fields query is like

```
 select * from table 
    where field in (1,2,3) 
    and field1 in (5,4) 
    and field2 in (6)
    or field2 is null //it always show results with null and 6
// but field1 and field2 are not matter are neglected
```

i want something like this may be this is the right approach

```
select * from table 
        where field in (1,2,3) 
        and field1 in (5,4) 
        and (field2 in (6)
        or field2 is null) //extra parenthesis so field 2 should have 6 or null but it should **and** field1, field2
```

any hint how i can achieve filed2 when has null and a value i.e [null, 6] should do something like this

```
(1 ,2,3 ) && (5,4) && (6 || null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback in where clause
Like:

```
$query->where(function($q) use ($field2, $searchArray) {
   $q->whereIn($field2, $searchArray)->orWhereNull($field2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a subquery, change :

```
$query->where($field2 , null);
```

to,

```
$query->where('field2', function($q) use($ans3){
    $q->whereIn('field2', $ans3)
      ->orWhereNull('field2')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try removing/unsetting the null key before passing the array into the where query,
if `array_filter($field2);` doesn't work correctly
try this post [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements/38081606#38081606)

Comment: i have null values in my DB and can be searched