# Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in: filename.

Tags: php

```
function convert($currencyType)
{
    $that = $this;
    return $result = function () use ($that) 
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyType, $this->ratio))
                return false;

        return ($this->ratio[$currencyType] * $this->money); //a float number
    };
}

$currency = new Currency();
echo $currency->convert('EURO');
```

What's wrong?

I'm getting the error message:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string
```

Comment: Your `convert()` function returns a function.  Then you're trying to coerce it into a string by `echo()`ing it.

Comment: But the closure returns a float/false to the $result?

Comment: And your `$this` references inside the Closure should be `$that` instead. They might have changed that in 5.4 thought; not sure.

Comment: You would actually have to call the resulting closure to get the float.  Why are you using a closure here?

Comment: Ah.  Lemme give you a formal answer...

Comment: The closure is a function, which is never called here... Unfortunately PHP (5.3 at least) can't do the required `echo $currency->convert('EURO')();` here, so it'd have to be `$callback = $currency->convert('EURO'); echo $callback();`, but _why_ use a closure in the first place?

Comment: I've just replied this question above. It's for learning purposes. I just want to do it with closures.

Answer (score 8):

Couple of issues:

1. Because you're returning a closure, you have to first assign the closure to a variable, and then call the function
2. Your `$this` references won't work inside a closure (which is why you're `use`ing `$that` instead)
3. You need to also use `$currencyType` to access it in the closure's scope

---

```
function convert($currencyType)
{
    $that =& $this; // Assign by reference here!
    return $result = function () use ($that, $currencyType) // Don't forget to actually use $that
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyType, $that->ratio))
                return false;

        return ($that->ratio[$currencyType] * $that->money); //a float number
    };
}

$currency = new Currency();
$convert = $currency->convert('EURO');
echo $convert(); // You're not actually calling the closure until here!
```

Comment: One question, though. Why if (!in_array($currencyType, $that->ratio)) return false; always returns false? $currencyType = 'EURO' and print_r($that->ratio) correctly outputs the array.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make function between parentheses and add parentheses when closing the function.

```
function convert($currencyType)
{
    $that = $this;
    return $result = (function () use ($that) 
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyType, $this->ratio))
                return false;

        return ($this->ratio[$currencyType] * $this->money); //a float number
    })();
}

$currency = new Currency();
echo $currency->convert('EURO');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the `return` there and do:

```
$result = function () use ($that) 
{
    if (!in_array($currencyType, $this->ratio))
            return false;

    return ($this->ratio[$currencyType] * $this->money); //a float number
};
return $result();
```

Also, are you realizing you are not using `$that` inside the function?

By the way, why do you need an anonymous function there? Just do:

```
function convert($currencyType)
{
    if (!in_array($currencyType, $this->ratio))
        return false;

    return ($this->ratio[$currencyType] * $this->money); //a float number
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it with closures. I know it's not necessary because I can do it without closures myself. I just want to use closures for learning purposes.

Comment: @LisaMiskovsky, closures can be stored in variables. Therefore `$var = function() {...}` will store that function in a variable. This is just not the place where to use anonymous functions. Don't learn bad things from the start. When you'll need closure you'll know how to use them.

Comment: Can you give me an example where it is a good place to use closures?

Comment: @LisaMiskovsky [Just take a look at here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147400/why-use-anonymous-function).

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use closures similar to blocks in Ruby, e.g. rather than doing say 
```if($that=='foo') $this='bar'; 
elseif($that=='dee') $this='dum';```
write it as: ```$this = function() { 
if($that=='foo') return 'bar';
elseif($that=='dee') return 'dum'; 
}``` except its nowhere near as concise as Ruby would be: ```ruby this = { if that='foo' then 'bar' elsif that='dee' then 'dum' }```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Currency {
    function convert($currencyType)
    {
        if (!in_array($currencyType, $this->ratio))
             return false;
        return ($this->ratio[$currencyType] * $this->money); //a float number
    }
}

$currency = new Currency();
echo $currency->convert('EURO');
```

You are defining a lambda function.  You don't need it.  Also, you should be using [bcmul()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) if this is to have any kind of accuracy; floats in PHP will give you funky results.