# PHP 5.4 Anonymous Function in Array undefine

Tags: php, arrays, variables, indexing, undefined

This is PHP 5.4 code...

```
<?php
function abc($YesNo){return $YesNo["value"];}
$YesNo = array("value"=>"No","text"=>"No");
$x = array("active"=>function(){return abc($YesNo);});
echo $x['active']();
?>
```

**Notice: Undefined variable: YesNo on line 7**
**Output Should be : Yes**

if i directly put array in code by replace $YesNo like

```
<?php
function abc($YesNo){return $YesNo["value"];}
$x = array("active"=>function(){return abc(array("value"=>"Yes","text"=>"Yes"));});
echo $x['active']();
?>
```

**output : Yes**
which is correct output. Now what's the problem in first code. I need that for re-usability

Comment: `$YesNo` isn't in the scope of the anonymous function.  Also, that's not what I would call "reusable" code.

Comment: how to handle this variable then

Comment: Use `function() { global $YesNo; return abc($YesNo); }`

Comment: I suggest reading this post about anonymous functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4147510/870729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide your anonymous function with a parameter:

```
$x = array("active"=>function($param){return abc($param);});
```

then you call it:

```
echo $x['active']($YesNo);
```

You may use the `use` keyword to make your function aware of an external variable:

```
$x = array("active"=>function() use ($YesNo) {return abc($YesNo);});
```

but it would be quite against the idea of reusability, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

You can use `use` for passing data to a closure.

```
<?php
function abc($YesNo){return $YesNo["value"];}
$YesNo = array("value"=>"No","text"=>"No");
$x = array("active"=>function() use ($YesNo) {return abc($YesNo);});
echo $x['active']();
?>
```

Comment: o mine, i will hate anonymous function if they are handle like this use($YesNo)... what a strange syntax

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your variable is not accessible within the function due to [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Because the array is defined *outside* of the function, it is not by default available *inside* the function.

There's a couple of solutions

**Disclaimer:** These are intended to fit within the scope of the question.  I understand that they are not necessarily best practice, which would require a larger discussion

First Option:
You can declare the array within the function, like below.  This is useful if you don't need access to it outside of the function.

```
function abc($YesNo){
    $YesNo = array("value"=>"No","text"=>"No");
    return $YesNo["value"];
}
```

Second Option:
Within your abc function, you can add the line `global $YesNo`.  This is useful if you **do** need access to the array outside of the function:

```
function abc($YesNo){
    global $YesNo;
    return $YesNo["value"];
}
```

Other options exist (such as moonwave99's answer).

Finally:
Why are you putting an anonymous function within the array of $x? Seems like a path that will lead to problems down the road....

Answer (score 1):

Your variable $YesNo needs to be visible in the scope of your anonymous function. You need to add global $YesNo as the first statement in that function:

So

```
$x = array("active"=>function(){return abc($YesNo);});
```

becomes

```
$x = array("active"=>function(){global $YesNo; return abc($YesNo);});
```

... also "value"=>"No" should be "value"=>"Yes" if you want it to return "Yes"